# How to abort on any message generated?

Tags: message-coding, interruption

Mathematica is a bit unusual as a programming language because it never stops on messages, regardless of whether the message is an error, a warning or just an informative message. It simply prints the message and continues with evaluation.  This can cause an avalanche of messages and unpredictable behaviour (e.g. memory may get filled up, bringing the machine to a halt with swapping---this is what happened to me)

**Is there a way to immediately abort when *any* message is generated?**

Requirements:

1. if a message would be printed, always abort.
2. if no message would be printed, don't abort.
3. do print the first message so I have a hint about what went wrong
4. the mechanism should work with parallel computations and should abort the full evaluation (i.e. main kernel and all parallel kernels)

There are many ways to handle message printing, including `On`/`Off`, `Quiet`, and possibly others (such as setting some system options).  The solution should work well with these.  I am afraid manually handling all possible situations is too fragile (there's always a chance something got left out).

I found a [solution on MathGroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2005/Apr/msg00127.html) which aborts, but does not print the message.

*I suspect there must exist a robust and simple solution because the Debug palette has a "Break on messages" option.*

Comment: Related stackoverflow link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987162/how-to-tell-mathematica-to-quit-upon-a-debug-error

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I found a robust solution described [in this MathGroup message by Maxim Rytin](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/YxTwWVL_UCg/IrKs9bhtsdkJ):

```
messageHandler = If[Last[#], Abort[]] &

Internal`AddHandler["Message", messageHandler]
```

This will abort the computation whenever a message would be printed.

It can be turned off using

```
Internal`RemoveHandler["Message", messageHandler]
```

Alternatively this can be temporarily applied to a piece of code like this:

```
Internal`HandlerBlock[
 {"Message", messageHandler},
 (* ... code here ... *)
]
```

The currently set message handlers can be retrieved using

```
Internal`Handlers["Message"]
```

(`` Internal`Handlers[] `` will return all existing handlers)

Whenever a message is generated, `Hold[message, printed]` is passed to all "Message" handler functions where `message` is the message text and `printed` is True is the message would be printed, `False` otherwise.

The debugging palette appears to use the same mechanism to break on messages.

---

To make it work with parallel evaluations, one can simply register the same handler on all kernels using `ParallelEvaluate`.

Comment: Caveat: functions such as `Reduce`, `Refine` and `Solve` can pass messages to handlers which have `printed=True` but are somehow never printed. These include `FindMinimum::fmmp` and `N::meprec`, which I'm guessing are harmless.

Comment: This functionality has made its way into a top-level function (sorta) with ``GeneralUtilities`WithMessageHandler`` which turns messages into `Failure` objects.

Answer (score 19):

What about something like this?

```
Function[i, {i, ParallelEvaluate[i]};, HoldFirst][
 Unprotect[Message, Check, Quiet];
 Module[{$guardMes = True, $guardChck = True, $guardQuiet = True},
  Message[args___ /; $guardMes] := Block[{$guardMes = False},
    Message[args];
    If[Head[First@{args}] =!= $Off, Abort[]];
    ];
  Quiet[args___ /; $guardQuiet] := Block[{$guardQuiet = False, $guardMes = False},
     Quiet[args]
    ];
  Check[args___ /; $guardChck] := Block[{$guardChck = False, $guardMes = False},
     Check[args]
    ];
  ]
 ]
```

**EDIT** to try to reflect Szabolcs's and Sjoerd's concerns

```
Function[i, {i, ParallelEvaluate[i]};, HoldFirst][
  Module[{$guardMes = True},
    OnMessageAbort[] := (
      Unprotect[Message];
      Message[args___ /; $guardMes && Head[First@{args}] =!= $Off] :=          
       Block[{$guardMes = False, flag = False},
        Internal`InheritedBlock[{$MessagePrePrint},
         $MessagePrePrint = 
          With[{fn = $MessagePrePrint}, 
           Function[i, flag = True; fn[i], HoldAll]];
         Message[args];
         If[flag, Abort[];]
         ]
        ];
       Protect[Message]);
    OffMessageAbort[] := (
      Unprotect[Message];
      Quiet[
       Message[args___ /; $guardMes && Head[First@{args}] =!= $Off] =.];
      Protect[Message];
      )
    ];
  ];
OnMessageAbort[ker_] := ParallelEvaluate[OnMessageAbort[], ker];
OnMessageAbort[All] := (ParallelEvaluate[OnMessageAbort[]]; 
   OnMessageAbort[]);
OffMessageAbort[ker_] := ParallelEvaluate[OffMessageAbort[], ker];
OffMessageAbort[All] := (ParallelEvaluate[OffMessageAbort[]]; 
   OffMessageAbort[]);
```

You run that once, and it defines (On/Off)MessageAbort[] in all kernels. You can call
OnMessageAbort[] to turn it on on the kernel you run that, or OnMessageAbort[kernel] from the main kernel to turn it on on a particular kernel, just like the second argument to ParallelEvaluate.
OnMessageAbort[All] turns it on in all of them. Same goes for OffMessageAbort

Comment: I just used `ParallelEvaluate` instead of `DistributeDefinitions`, and now it works fine in parallel too.  I have some ideas why `DistributeDefinitions` doesn't work here, but the workaround is good enough for now.  Please also see https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/0hw5IkrdsTU/v2404uYo9GsJ

Comment: Edited with ParallelEvaluate and as you said it works. Thanks for the link

Comment: @Szabolcs, reading your question on your link, when you do x=1;ParallelEvaluate[x], it returns {1,1} because your main kernel evaluates the result {x,x} returned from the parallel kernels, not because x was automatically synched

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, you are right, `ParallelEvaluate` does not auto-sync (`ParallelEvaluate@Hold@Evaluate[x]` can be used for testing).  But `Parallelize` does auto-distribute definitions, so my original problem that I asked about was valid :-)

Comment: +1, good stuff! My version does not yet quite work for parallel, and your does. Nice!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a Protect at the end for completeness? And perhaps it's a good idea to add some code to restore the default situation?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries yeah. It isn't even turned into a function yet, just a code cell.

Comment: There are some more problems with this: 1. `Check` should not prevent aborting because a message is still printed when using `Check` alone (without `Quiet`).  2. The second argument of `Quiet` is not supported.   suppose I could fix this by adding more code for specific situations, but it introduces a lot of complexity.  Generally:  the calculation should be aborted if a message would be printed.  It should not be aborted if no message would be printed.

Comment: @Szabolcs, let me know what you think of the edited version

Answer (score 16):

The easiest and, so far, the best solution I have found is the following:

```
(* Put the following two lines at the top of every notebook. *)
messageHandler = If[Last[#], Interrupt[]] & ;
Internal`AddHandler["Message", messageHandler];
```

The above code is slightly modified from Szabolcs's solution at the beginning of this thread. I changed `Abort` to `Interrupt`. The latter seems to work immediately, while it appears that `Abort` may be waiting for some portion of the evaluation to finish before stopping everything.

Comment: Hi Ralph, thanks for the answer! I formatted your code for you. If you would like more information about how to do this yourself, [have a look at this page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thank you verbeia! As you correctly surmised, I could not figure out how to get the code to look right.

Answer (score 13):

I've written a function `CheckReturn` that attempts to behave just like [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check), except that it returns immediately if a message is generated. Also, if [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet) wrappers are used external or internal to `CheckReturn`, the behavior is consistent with how [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check) works. The code is given at the end. Here are some examples:

```
CheckReturn[1/0; Print[2], $Failed]
Check[1/0; Print[2], $Failed]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> $Failed
>
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> 2
>
> $Failed

Notice that using `CheckReturn`, 2 was not printed. So far so good. Now, let's use an external [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet):

```
Quiet @ CheckReturn[1/0; Print[2], $Failed]
Quiet @ Check[1/0; Print[2], $Failed]
```

> $Failed
>
> 2
>
> $Failed

In both cases the message is detected and failure expression is returned, but `CheckReturn` returns immediately without printing 2. Similarly, if we use an internal [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet):

```
CheckReturn[ Quiet[1/0]; Print[2], $Failed]
Check[ Quiet[1/0]; Print[2], $Failed]
```

> 2
>
> 2

In both cases the internal [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet) is respected, and the message is not detected. `CheckReturn` has the option `"CheckQuietedMessages"->False`. If we set this option to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True), than the internal [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet) is disregarded:

```
CheckReturn[ Quiet[1/0]; Print[2], $Failed, "CheckQuietedMessages"->True ]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> $Failed

Just like [`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check) has a 3-arg version where explicit messages can be specified, the same is possible with `CheckReturn`:

```
CheckReturn[ 1/0; Print[2], $Failed, Power::infy ]
```

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> $Failed

Finally, if messages are turned off, than `CheckReturn` ignores them as well:

```
Off[Power::infy]
CheckReturn[ 1/0; Print[2], $Failed, Power::infy]
Check[1/0; Print[2], $Failed, Power::infy]
```

> 2
>
> 2

Note that I didn't consider parallel behavior. Here is the code:

```
SetAttributes[CheckReturn,HoldAll]
Options[CheckReturn]={"CheckQuietedMessages"->False};

CheckReturn[body_,return_, OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{handler,flag},
    With[{stack = If[TrueQ@OptionValue["CheckQuietedMessages"], _, quietStack[]]},
        handler[Hold[mess_Message, True]]:=Throw[$Failed,flag];
        handler[Hold[mess:Message[mn_,___], False]] /; quietedMessageCheck[HoldForm[mn],stack] := Throw[
            Hold[mess],
            flag
        ]
    ];

    Catch[
        Internal`HandlerBlock[{"Message",handler},body],
        flag,
        (ReleaseHold[#];return)&
    ]
]

CheckReturn[body_, return_, m_, OptionsPattern[]]:=Module[{pred,handler, flag},
    pred = messagePredicate[m];
    (
    With[{stack = If[TrueQ@OptionValue["CheckQuietedMessages"], _, quietStack[]]},
        handler[Hold[mess:Message[mn_?pred,___], True]] := Throw[$Failed,flag];
        handler[Hold[mess:Message[mn_?pred,___], False]] /; quietedMessageCheck[HoldForm[mn],stack] := Throw[
            Hold[mess],
            flag
        ]
    ];

    Catch[
        Internal`HandlerBlock[{"Message", handler}, body],
        flag,
        (ReleaseHold[#];return)&
    ]
    ) /; pred=!=$Failed
]

SetAttributes[{messagePredicate, messageRules}, HoldAll]
messagePredicate[m_] := Replace[
    messageRules[m],
    r:Except[$Failed] :> Function[Null,ReplaceAll[HoldForm[#], r], HoldAll]
]

messageRules[MessageName[General, m_]] := HoldForm[MessageName[_,m]] -> True
messageRules[MessageName[t_, m_]] := HoldForm[MessageName[t,m]] -> True

messageRules[m:{__MessageName}] := messageRules /@ Unevaluated[m]

messageRules[m_String] := Replace[
Hold[m] /. $MessageGroups,
  {
  Hold[mn:{__MessageName}] :> messageRules[mn],
  _ :> (Message[CheckReturn::mgre, m]; $Failed)
    }
]

messageRules[m_] := (Message[Message::name, HoldForm[m]]; $Failed)

quietStack[] := Alternatives @@ (Stack/.Internal`QuietStatus[])[[1,All,1]]

quietedMessageCheck[m_HoldForm, stack_] := Count[
    First[MessageList /. Internal`QuietStatus[]] /. m -> True,
    {True, stack}
] > 0
```

Answer (score 9):

The following works pretty well, at least in Mathematica 10:

1. On the menu bar, go to Evaluation/Debugger Controls/Show Debugger
   Tools Window.
2. On the window that pops up, check the box to "Break
   at Messages"

It will then stop and display a green box around the code that is outputting an error message.

Comment: Actually I was aware of this when asking the question (see the very last paragraph), but I needed a way that doesn't require the front end.  It turns out that the method used in the accepted solution is the same the debugger uses.  It's good to point out this possibility explicitly though, so +1.

Comment: Same option is directly in the Evaluation->Debugger popup in Mathematica 11.1 (checking or unchecking the described "Dhow Debugger Tools Windows" doesn't open a popup for me)

Answer (score 8):

There were some attempts on that in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176612/setting-up-diagnostic-error-messages-in-large-mathematica-projects) discussion. I also have this functionality in my `debug` function posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362170/how-to-find-line-where-error-occurred-in-mathematica-notebook/8363717#8363717)

Comment: Which one do you recommend for practical use?  It should work in an environment with no front end, and I need to generalize it for parallel evaluation.

Comment: @Szabolcs I did not use ot for parallel, but I was debugging serious staff with `debug`, like stack traces with depth 30 or 50, digging deep into internal stuff, and it all worked quite well. So, I'd rather extend `debug` for parallel, because it serves me very well. It also is useful in that it gives you the (sort of a) stack trace.

Comment: @belisarius's idea works quite well, I'll take a detailed look at `debug` (for the future) after I've debugged this thing...

Comment: Your `debug` function looks very useful.  There's one big problem though: it breaks on `Quiet`ed messages as well.  My code, as well as at least some package functions, uses `Quiet` at certain positions.

Comment: @Szabolcs I will look into it

Comment: It was ultimately `debug[]` that saved me today.  If/when you update it, could you consider copying it here?

Comment: @Szabolcs I spent the last hour trying to get it work with parallel and `Quiet`. I am on the way, but not yet quite there, and probably have no more time to spend on it now. I will surely update it here once done, and put it high in my SE-related to-do list. Out of curiosity: how did you manage to use it if it does not work for parallel stuff? We could move this to chat if you wish.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2432/discussion-between-szabolcs-and-leonid-shifrin)