# Resource management in Mathematica

Tags: guidelines, resource-management

I am using a library that has functions like `createSomeObject[]` and `deleteSomeObject[obj]`.  It is an interface to a C language library and it reflects how the C library is designed.

How can I make sure that when I have code similar to

```
Module[{obj},
  obj = createSomeObject[];
  (* some code here *)
  blackBoxFunction[];
  (* some code here *)
  deleteSomeObject[obj];
  (* ... *)
]
```

then the objects will always be safely cleaned up, even if the computation is aborted in the middle of the `Module` or `blackBoxFunction[]` does something unexpected (`Throw[]` or something else I didn't think of)?

In C++ we have [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for this.  **What is the most usual / idiomatic way to do safe resource management this in Mathematica?**

Note that even when only using built-in functions, this problem might come up with e.g. opening and closing file streams ([it is very important to close streams](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/XcK_fkeTQY0/discussion)).  Even some packages shipping with Mathematica, such as [TetGenLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/TetGenLink/ref/TetGenCreate.html), require explicit resource management.

---

Finally, is it possible to design such libraries in a way that avoids explicit `deleteSomeObject[obj]` calls?  Is it possible to integrate the library with Mathematica's built-in reference counting and garbage collection?  I found the `"RemoveSymbol"` handler ([see `` Internal`Handlers[] ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1545/12)), but it only seems to trigger on explicit `Remove[]`, not when [`Temporary` symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Temporary.html) (such as `Module` variables) are cleaned up.

---

**Update:** If you need this specifically for a LibraryLink library in Mathematica 10.0, look up [Managed Library Expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html#353220453). This feature was not yet available when I wrote the question.

Comment: I am sure I read a similar question on StackOverflow, but I can't find it now ...

Comment: FWIW, the StackOverflow question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365794/reliable-clean-up-in-mathematica).

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/136005)

Answer (score 22):

There is an undocumented function, `CheckAll`, that can be used for this purpose.  It dates back to at least version 7.  All the usual caveats about undocumented functions apply -- it might not be supported in future releases, there may be gaps in its functionality, etc.  Buyer beware.

The usage information looks like this:

[image: usage screenshot]

The usage text is slightly in error as the *control* arguments are wrapped in `Hold` rather than `HoldComplete`.

`CheckAll` can be used to detect all manner of non-local exits, such as:

```
CheckAll[Abort[], List]
(* {$Aborted, Hold[Abort[]]} *)

CheckAll[Throw[1], List]
(* {$Aborted, Hold[Throw[1]]} *)

CheckAll[Goto[a], List]
(* {$Aborted, Hold[Goto[a]]} *)

CheckAll[MemoryConstrained[Range@1000, 100], List]
(* {$Aborted, Hold[]} *)

CheckAll[TimeConstrained[Pause[1000], 1], List]
(* {$Aborted, Hold[]} *)
```

We can use this function to build `unwindProtect`, a control structure that assures that a clean-up expression is evaluated after any non-local exit of its body:

```
ClearAll @ unwindProtect
SetAttributes[unwindProtect, HoldAll]
unwindProtect[body_, cleanup_] :=
  CheckAll[body, HoldComplete] /.
    ( cleanup
    ; { _[_, _[r__]] :> r
      , _[r_, _[]] :> r
      }
    )
```

It starts by evaluating the body, guarded by `CheckAll`.  Then it evaluates the clean-up expression.  Finally, it returns either the pending non-local control actions or, if there are none, the return value of the body (which might be a held `Sequence`).

Here are some examples of its use:

```
hi[] := Print@"hi"
bye[] := Print@"bye"
fail[] := Print@"FAIL!"

unwindProtect[hi[]; Abort[], bye[]]
(* During evaluation of In[75]:= hi
   During evaluation of In[75]:= bye
   Out[75]= $Aborted *)

Catch @ unwindProtect[hi[]; Throw[1]; fail[], bye[]]
(* During evaluation of In[76]:= hi
   During evaluation of In[76]:= bye
   Out[76]= 1 *)

Module[{n = 0}
, Label[a]
; If[n < 2, unwindProtect[Print["hi ", ++n]; Goto[a], Print["bye ", n]]]
]
(* hi 1
   bye 1
   hi 2
   bye 2 *)
```

It even handles some tricky cases:

```
Catch@unwindProtect[hi[];Throw[Unevaluated[Abort[]]], bye[]]
(* During evaluation of In[82]:= hi
   During evaluation of In[82]:= bye
   Out[82]= $Aborted *)

Catch@unwindProtect[hi[];Throw[Unevaluated[Throw[$Failed]]], bye[]]
(* During evaluation of In[83]:= hi
   During evaluation of In[83]:= bye
   Out[83]= $Failed *)
```

`unwindProtect` can be used to build a still higher-level control structure (`withSetup`) that supports the declaration of `Module`-like variables, with sequential assignment and resource-cleanup expressions:

```
ClearAll[withSetup]
SetAttributes[withSetup, HoldAll]

withSetup[{}, body_] := body

withSetup[{var_ = val_; cleanup___, rest___}, body_] :=
  Module[{var = val}
  , unwindProtect[withSetup[{rest}, body], CompoundExpression[cleanup]]
  ]

withSetup[{var_ = val_, rest___}, body_] :=
  Module[{var = val}, withSetup[{rest}, body]]

w:withSetup[___] := (Message[withSetup::malformed, Short@HoldForm[w]]; Abort[])

withSetup::malformed = "``";
```

`withSetup` starts out resembling `Module`:

```
withSetup[{x = 1}, x + 1]
(* 2 *)
```

It differs from `Module` in that the variable assignments are performed sequentially:

```
withSetup[{x = 1, y = x + 1}, {x, y}]
(* {1, 2} *)
```

But the real value of `withSetup` is that it can be used to declare clean-up actions for each variable:

```
open[f_] := (Print["opened ", f]; file[f])
close[f_] := Print["closed ", f]

withSetup[{f = open["f1"]; close[f]}, f]
(* During evaluation of In[152]:= opened f1
   During evaluation of In[152]:= closed file[f1]
   Out[154]= file[f1] *)
```

... and those clean-up actions are performed even in the face of a non-local return:

```
Catch @ withSetup[{f = open["f1"]; close[f]}, Throw["early exit"]]
(* During evaluation of In[160]:= opened f1
   During evaluation of In[160]:= closed file[f1]
   Out[160]= early exit *)
```

Clean-up actions are performed in reverse order from their corresponding initializations:

```
withSetup[
  { file1 = open["f1"]; close[file1]
  , file2 = open["f2"]; close[file2]
  , files = {file1, file2}
  }
, doStuffWith[file1, file2, files]
]
(* During evaluation of In[155]:= opened f1
   During evaluation of In[155]:= opened f2
   During evaluation of In[155]:= closed file[f2]
   During evaluation of In[155]:= closed file[f1]
   doStuffWith[file[f1],file[f2],{file[f1],file[f2]}] *)
```

`withSetup` assumes that any variable initialization that is a compound expression is initialized using the first part of the expression, and is cleaned up using the remaining parts.  One is free to write `{var = (init1; init2); cleanup1; cleanup2}` if desired.

Beware that any errors or other non-local exits from the clean-up actions can cause all kinds of strange behaviour.  Clean-up actions should be foolproof, with no reasonable chance of failure.  Wrap them in `CheckAbort`, `AbortProtect` or even `unwindProtect` if there is any doubt and circumstances demand it.  `unwindProtect` does *not* do this automatically, although it could be changed to do so according to one's personal preference (I prefer to see the errors rather than muffle them).

**Update**

I subsequently discovered that `CheckAll` muffles all messages generated by the exit function.  Furthermore, any messages from the main expression are also muffled in such circumstances.  Here is a revised version of `unwindProtect` that performs some gymnastics to preserve the main messages and to inform the user when a clean-up expression fails:

```
ClearAll@unwindProtect
SetAttributes[unwindProtect, HoldAll]
unwindProtect[body_, cleanup_] :=
  CheckAll[body, HoldComplete] /.
    ( CheckAll[cleanup, HoldComplete] /. _[v_, _[c__]] :>
        Check[
          Message[unwindProtect::cleanupFailed
          , HoldForm @ cleanup
          , HoldForm @ {v}
          , HoldForm @ {c}
          ]
        , Null
        ]
    ; { _[_, _[r__]] :> r
      , _[r_, _[]] :> r
      }
    )

unwindProtect::cleanupFailed =
  "Cleanup expression failed: ``, results: ``, controls:  ``";
```

Comment: Wow, great find!

Comment: Somehow I missed this answer, and only discovered it by accident when looking at the old SO question on this, and seeing your more recent comment there. I've been using your `CleanUp` function from that old post extensively, but this seems a better alternative. Big +1.

Comment: ``System`Private`HasAnyCodesQ[CheckAll]`` will give `True`,which mean it is a *kernel function*,so it will not be abandon in future version as I know.

Comment: Please consider adding this to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/805/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard [Done](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208942/142).  I chose to emphasize the use of ``Internal`WithLocalSettings`` over `CheckAll` as the former now seems to be the most reliable way to deal with non-local exits.

Answer (score 15):

This question was indeed discussed on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365794/reliable-clean-up-in-mathematica). I am usually using the version of `CleanUp` function by WReach, from that answer. It is however not fully bulletproof, as I noted in comments to that answer. Particular pieces of code which are problematic are nested exceptions or aborts like these:

```
Throw[Unevaluated[Abort[]]]
```

or

```
Throw[Unevaluated[Throw[$Failed]],
```

which are a problem because of the way untagged exceptions are caught (there is no way to intercept whatever is being thrown with them in unevaluated form). My personal opinion is that untagged exceptions are a language defect.

That said, `CleanUp` seems generally reliable, since the cases I described are rather unlikely, so I'd go ahead and use that (I do, actually). Generally, my feeling however is that there can be no totally proof reliable function to do that currently, and that this has to have a native support from the language (which is currently lacking). This view was expressed by WReach in his cited answer, and I share it.

There is also  [`` Internal`WithLocalSettings ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7586910/695132), however this one appears to not handle exceptions properly.

**EDIT**

Here is the setup I suggest. The code and an example follow.

#### Code

First, I reproduce here the `CleanUp` function from the cited answer by @WReach, to make this answer self-contained:

```
SetAttributes[CleanUp, HoldAll]
CleanUp[expr_, cleanup_] :=
  Module[{exprFn, result, abort = False, rethrow = True, seq}, 
    exprFn[] := expr;
    result = 
      CheckAbort[
         Catch[Catch[result = exprFn[]; rethrow = False; result], _, 
           seq[##] &], abort = True];
    cleanup;
    If[abort, Abort[]];
    If[rethrow, Throw[result /. seq -> Sequence]];
    result]
```

This is a custom `Module`, which would remove its variables explicitly. Note that it uses a custom `remove` function.

```
ClearAll[removingModule];
SetAttributes[removingModule, HoldAll];
removingModule[vars_, body_] :=
  Module[vars,
    CleanUp[
      body,
      ReleaseHold@Replace[
         HoldComplete[vars],
         {HoldPattern[a_Symbol = rhs_] :> remove[a], 
             HoldPattern[a_Symbol] :> remove[a]},
         {2}
      ]]];
```

Here is a custom `remove` function

```
ClearAll[remove, $removeHandler];
SetAttributes[remove, HoldFirst];
remove[s_Symbol, removeHandler_: $removeHandler ] :=
     CleanUp[$removeHandler[s], Remove[s]];
$removeHandler = Identity;
```

This will allow us to use familiar `Module` syntax in definitions (perhaps, incomplete, but illustrates the idea):

```
(* Note: there may be other rules added here *)
ClearAll[lex];
lex /: SetDelayed[lex@def_, rhs_] :=
   SetDelayed @@ 
     Prepend[Hold[rhs] /. Module -> removingModule, Unevaluated[def]];
```

This will generate custom dynamic environments, with a given handler which is invoked on `remove`:

```
ClearAll[withRemoveHandler];
withRemoveHandler[handler_] :=
  Function[code,
    Block[{$removeHandler  = handler}, code],
    HoldAll];
```

#### Example

We first define some function with our syntax:

```
ClearAll[myFunction];
lex@myFunction[x_] := Module[{y = 1, z = 2}, x + y + z];
```

Test:

```
?myFunction

Global`myFunction
myFunction[x_]:=removingModule[{y = 1, z = 2}, x+y+z]
```

Now, make a custom environment, where we will print the symbols before they get `Remove`-d:

```
env = withRemoveHandler[Function[s, Print[Unevaluated[s]], HoldAll]];
```

Now, execute code inside this environment:

```
In[98]:= env@myFunction[1]

During evaluation of In[98]:= y$705
During evaluation of In[98]:= z$705

Out[98]= 4
```

#### Summary of the approach

The above code may allow one to automate handling of resources in situations described in the original question (constructs like `Module[{obj}, obj = createCustomObject[], ...]`), while using the syntax maximally close to the standard one. You have to prefix your definitions with `lex@`, and execute code in a dynamic environment where you enable a handler that you want.

Comment: Do you have some more information on ``Internal`WithLocalSettings` ``?  It seems to be just what I asked for.  How does it fail?  In a quick test I did notice that it *sometimes, but not always* prevents exceptions from being caught, which is very weird behaviour:  ``Catch[
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[Print["begin"], Throw[1]; 
  Print["not printed"], Print["end"]]
 ]`` doesn't work correctly, but ``Catch[
 Internal`WithLocalSettings[Print["begin"], Throw[1]; 
  Print["not printed"], nothing]
 ]`` does.

Comment: @Szabolcs Unfortunately I don't. It looks like ``Internal`WithLocalSettings`` has its own way to unwind the stack, which conflicts with `Catch`. I don't really know how it works. One thing which is strange is that in the first case (when it leaks an exception), it returns `$Aborted[]`, meaning that some `Abort[]` is happening somewhere. It could be that it sends 3 different evaluations to the kernel via MathLink, and therefore, even when an exception is happening, we have no way to catch it. Why and what gets Aborted I have no idea.

Comment: I am still wishing for some kind of integration with the garbage collector ... then a plain `Module` would do

Comment: @Szabolcs Yes, I agree. I will actually delete the above comment, did not put much thinking in it (seems to be my problem for the past few days). You could use your own scoping construct, call it `myModule`, and get some similar structure there - this should be safe.

Comment: @Szabolcs I added some code which may address some of your concerns.

Comment: Despite some of the difficulties seen by Szabolcs, I find myself using ``Internal`WithLocalSettings`` quite a lot lately. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @rcollyer No problem. I actually ended up using `CleanUp` a lot, but not so much ``Internal`WithLocalSettings``.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've been looking at ``Internal`WithLocalSetting``, and I can only get the behavior you're seeing when `Print` is in the third argument.

Comment: @Leonid When you say the WithLocalSettings doesn't work with exceptions, you only mean this case, right? --> `Catch@WithLocalSettings[pre, Throw[...], post]`.  But not this case: `WithLocalSettings[pre, Catch@Throw[...], post]`  I need to use the second one.

Comment: @Szabolcs If you catch an exception inside your main code, then for the purposes of `WithLocalSettings`, your code does not throw an exception, so it should probably work. In any case, I switched to use WReach's version of `CleanUp` which is included in the post above - it seems more robust to me. One thing I did not check is how good is `WithLocalSettings` in catching system-level `Abort`-s,  which IIRC are not always cought by `CheckAbort` and `AbortProtect` (but I don't remember the details).

Answer (score 11):

I would use the Execute Around Block pattern, which is superficially similar to RAII in c++.  A [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4176381/198315) is what I use for ensuring that streams are closed after execution:

```
OpenAndRead[file_String, fcn_]:=
Module[{strm, res},
  strm = OpenRead[file];
  res = CheckAbort[ fcn[strm], $Aborted ];
  Close[strm];
  If[res === $Aborted, Abort[], res] (* Edited to allow Abort to propagate *)
]
```

Here, I use `CheckAbort` to prevent `Abort` from propagating out of my code until it I've closed the stream. It's use is simply,

```
fcn[ file_String, <otherparams> ] := OpenAndRead[file, fcn[#, <otherparams>]&]
fcn[ file_InputStream, <otherparams> ] := <fcn body>
```

But, that is inconvenient to use. In the previous answer, I suggested a facility for automatically generating that code. Since then, I've determined that is a poor strategy, and instead suggest the creation of a `Block` or `Module` type scoping construct:

```
SetAttributes[ReadBlock, HoldAll];
ReadBlock[filename_String, body_]:= ReadBlock[{filename, file}, body]

ReadBlock[{filename_String,file_Symbol}, body_] :=
 OpenAndRead[filename, Function[{file}, body]]
```

Then, the definition of `fcn` is

```
fcn[ file_String, <otherparams> ] := ReadBlock[{file, strm}, <body]
```

---

For your case, I'd set it up like this

```
SetAttributes[ProtectedBlock, HoldAll];
ProtectedBlock[{openfcn_, closefcn_},body_]:= 
    ProtectedBlock[{obj, openfcn, closefcn}, body]

ProtectedBlock[{obj_Symbol, openfcn_, closefcn_}, body_]:=
 Module[{res, obj},
    obj = openfcn;
    res = Check[ CheckAbort[ body, $Aborted ];closefcn , $Failed ];

    If[ 
      res === $Aborted, Abort[],
      res
    ]

 ]
```

Obviously, this needs a bit of work to properly rethrow the messages suppressed by `Check`, but it should be along the lines of what you are looking for.

---

**Edit**: Here's the final form of `ReadBlock` which I've renamed as `BlockStream`.

```
ClearAll[BlockStream];
SetAttributes[BlockStream, HoldAll];
SyntaxInformation[BlockStream] = {"ArgumentsPattern"->{_, _, _.}, 
          "LocalVariables" -> {"Solve", {1,1}}};
BlockStream[filename_, body_]:= 
    BlockStream[{file, filename}, OpenRead, body]
BlockStream[{file_Symbol, filename_}, body_]:= 
    BlockStream[{file, filename}, OpenRead, body]
BlockStream[filename_, op:(OpenRead | OpenWrite|OpenAppend), body_]:= 
    BlockStream[{file, filename}, op, body]
BlockStream[{file_Symbol, filename_}, op:(OpenRead | OpenWrite|OpenAppend), body_]:=
 Block[{file = op[filename], res, f, $TagLess},
  If[file ===$Failed, Return[$Failed]];
  (* 
 Catch added in case there is an uncaught Throw which would bypass 
    the Close[strm]. But, Catch[expr, _, f] would not catch tagless Throw, 
    so made Throw have dummy tag, $TagLess,
    which is stripped prior to rethrowing.
  *)
  res = Internal`InheritedBlock[{Throw},
         Unprotect[Throw];
         Throw[value_] := Throw[value, $TagLess];
   Catch[CheckAbort[body, $Aborted], _, f]
      ];
  Close[file];

  Which[
   res === $Aborted, Abort[],
   Head@res === f, If[Last@res===$TagLess, res = f[First@res] ]; 
                   Block[{f = Throw}, res],
   True, res
  ]
 ]
```

This works by executing `body` within an environment where the `Stream` is guaranteed to be closed regardless of what the code in `body` does. There are two main ways to use it, with or without specifying a symbol to associate with the stream. If a symbol is not passed in, via the `BlockStream[{file, filename}, ...]` syntax, the symbol `file` is set to the stream and is exposed to the code within `body`. A simple usage example is

```
BlockStream[{strm, FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "writefile"}]},
 OpenWrite,
 Write[strm, a^2, 1 + b^2]
 ]
```

where as you can see the symbol `strm` is accesible within the `body` of the function.

Note this converges in many ways with [Leonid's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1603/52), but it uses only a single `Catch`. To deal with a tagless `Throw`, I modified throws behavior to add the tag `$TagLess` whenever a tag isn't specified, and I deal with that later. This seems like the best way to ensure that whether it is tagged and tagless, `Throw` is always caught.

Comment: One problem I find with this is that this does not handle exceptions. And when you include exceptions, I think you are likely to end up with someting like `CleanUp`, for which I can not claim the authorship alas :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin you're right it doesn't handle exceptions. But, I find that if an exception escapes into my code from a library, then the library isn't well written. But, it could be adapted to do that. And, I had not actually read the code for `CleanUp` before, and it is very similar.

Comment: I am not sure regarding exceptions. Java has exceptions and most libraries throw some to the user in some cases, including run-time exceptions which are not checked by the compiler. Exceptions are the signal that something should go through the execution stack until it meets the proper handler. It often happens that your library is not the end of the stack, so you should simply pass it along, to let the user of your library handle that. Unless *your* code must handle them, you should allow them to pass along, *performing proper actions*, rather than have your code broken because of them ...

Comment: ... What I described is a common wisdom for large-scale software engineering say in Java. OTOH, in Mathematica exceptions are not widely used, and returning `$Failed` is preferred. I attribute that to the fact that for Mathematica applications (packages) large technology stacks are not typical, because large third-party Mathematica applications as components are not typical. As soon as larger body of Mathematica code available as components / frameworks accumulates, this may change. Besides, if you write a large app, you may wish some of your modules to throw exceptions.

Comment: The problem with returning `$Failed` is that this gives the user of your library no information on what happened. Therefore, s/he can not act accordingly, depending on the cause. An alternative is to return error codes, but this is cumbersome, and you have then to propagate all that to the function that *is* in the position to handle that. The point is, for a reusable component, it has no way to know which function would that be, since that depends on a particular application. So, exceptions are a way to pass the error information to a function which can handle that, making components reusable

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I agree, so allow me to rephrase. At the user level, exceptions should not be visible; at worst they should be translated into messages, and at best they should be handled within the library. We know that cannot always happen, but preventing them from escaping percolating up to the user is reasonable and a valid design goal.

Comment: Yes, sure, but *you* (as the one who supplies a general function such as `ProtectedBlock`) should aim at module developers more than users, IMO.  Because anyone who needs to use something like `CleanUp` or `ProtectedBlock`, better be considered a developer. One should make tools that one would like to use him/herself, not dumbed-down tools for hypothetical end users who must be protected from complexity. Such users get UI-s and final simple interfaces, behind which *everything* is hidden, and will never need `CleanUp`. This is not my thought (alas), but I fully agree with it.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, I don't disagree. But, as I said, my answer is incomplete, and should be treated as a direction to head, not the final destination. While I prefer not to deal with exceptions myself (and yes, I've done so in other types of code), I can see their utility. However, I'd prefer a lib with a polished interface for the less advanced users, and a more flexible API for the users/developers who need it. The `NDSolve` interface comes to mind.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I just think that tools like `CleanUp` are a signature of a developer-level coding, because releasing resources is always a lower-level operation compared to the final functionality you want to get, in my experience. I may well be wrong about it, this is just an opinion.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I don't think you're wrong, per se. I think it is very easy to encounter the need for such very early in mma usage which affects its learning curve. Of course, that thought makes me think I need to actually post fully working code. Let me think about what is needed to fully protect this code, and I'll put up a revision. It won't be this weekend, though.

Comment: There is no rush, I guess. I am sure you have more important things to do.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I added my updated version of `BlockStream` to this answer.

Comment: Big +1 this time :)

Answer (score 7):

According to the documentation, the [Managed Library Expressions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html#353220453) feature helps with this when using LibraryLink.

It makes it possible to create C-side data structures (using LibraryLink) which are automatically freed when the associated Mathematica expression is no longer referenced.

Answer (score 5):

Version 12.2 introduced [WithCleanup](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WithCleanup.html), an experimental but documented function to ensure safe resource disposal.

The example from the question would look like this when using `WithCleanup`:

```
Module[{obj},
  obj = createSomeObject[];
  WithCleanup[
    (* some code here *)
    blackBoxFunction[];
    (* some code here *)
    ,
    deleteSomeObject[obj];
  ]
  (* ... *)
]
```

`deleteSomeObject` is guaranteed to be called if control enters the `WithCleanup` expression whether or not the main expression terminates normally (barring catastrophic system failure such as a kernel crash).

There is also a three-argument form `WithCleanup[init, body, cleanup]` which allows initializations to be specified separately from the main body in which case those initializations will be protected from user aborts.  But note that the clean-up expression is called even if the initialization form fails so if the clean-up expression depends upon the successful completion of the initialization forms then the latter should be placed outside of the `WithCleanup` form as shown in the example.

Comment: The difference between `WithCleanup[init, body, cleanup]` and `WithCleanup[init; body, cleanup]` is that `init` is protected from user aborts only in the 3-argument form.

Comment: @JasonB. Thanks... I'll update the response.

Comment: @JasonB. is this basically a renaming of the old ``Internal`WithLocalSettings``?

Comment: @b3m2a1 exactly