# Skip header lines on import

Tags: import, text

When importing a data file what are the comment symbols for *Mathematica*?
That is, given a file like this

```
blabla
bulbul

1 2 6 54 7 ...
..
```

what symbol do I have to put in front of header lines so *Mathematica* skips them and starts reading at  the line `1 2 6 54 7 ...`. I tried `#`, which works in gnuplot, but that did not work.

I know that I could just tell *Mathematica* to skip the lines, but as I can control the file output, it would be nicer to use some kind of a tag.

Comment: The simplest way is to `Import[something][[n+1;;]]` where n is the number of "commented" line you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ReadList with header and foot lines](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44229/readlist-with-header-and-foot-lines)

Comment: At first glance, I thought this was a duplicate. It is not. The difference is that the number of header lines may be different each time, so it requires processing.

Comment: @Öskå Are you able to answer this question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65377/import-large-data-file-with-long-header-elegantly-unique-identifier-on-many-lin)? I am not sure whether it is related: I have header with four lines where unique identifier is specified by two lines.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an approach that handles interspersed comments in addition to "headers"

```
 FilePrint["test.txt"]
```

```
#comment
#comment
#comment
1 2 3
#c2
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

```
 ImportString[
     StringReplace[Import["test.txt", "Text"], 
         StartOfLine ~~ "#" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ EndOfLine ~~ "\n" -> ""], "Table"]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}

of course you can invent whatever convention you want or even a mix, eg..

```
 `StartOfLine ~~ {"#", "!", "%"} ~~ ...`
```

another variant:

```
 ImportString[StringJoin@Riffle[
      Select[StringSplit[Import["test.txt", "Text"], "\n"],
            StringTake[#, 1] != "#" &], "\n"], "Table"]
```

Even handle end-of-line comments:

```
#comment
1 2 3
#c2
4 5 6  #note 1
7 8 9
```

```
 ImportString[StringReplace[Import["test.txt", "Text"], {
      StartOfLine ~~ "#" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ EndOfLine ~~ "\n" -> "",
                     "#" ~~ Shortest[___] ~~ EndOfLine -> ""
                                       }], "Table"]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}

Tested on Windows by the way --  this might need some tweaking to handle different line endings on other systems

Comment: Strictly speaking your last example doesn't handle in-line comments, but only handles comments that are terminated by a line ending. In-line comments need a beginning and an end delimiter.

Comment: ok.. not sure what to call that but I'll fix..

Comment: @george2079, does your apprach require ImportString or, in any case, can it be adapted to import CSV files, skipping blocks of rows (of varying length) consisting entirely of `NullWords`?

Comment: Are you able to answer this question [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65377/import-large-data-file-with-long-header-elegantly-unique-identifier-on-many-lin)? I am not sure whether it is related: I have header with four lines where unique identifier is specified by two lines.

Answer (score 19):

I like to just import it and then filter it afterwards.

```
data = Cases[Import["file", "Table"], {_?NumberQ, ___}];
```

which will contain only those lines that start with a number.

Comment: I find this far more readable than george2079, upvote it! +1. Can someone explain why the other answer has got so many upvotes and this only 2?

Answer (score 17):

The Import command supports an option to ignore header lines. In many cases this is the easiest solution. For example:

```
dataStats = Import["C:/data/stats.csv", "CSV", HeaderLines -> 4];
```

Comment: This does not work for white-space separated numbers, right?

Comment: Where is this `Import` option documented?

Answer (score 5):

Here's one possibility.  I made a CSV file that imports looking like this:

```
data = Import["temp.csv"]
(* {{"header 1", ""}, {"header 2", ""}, {"#", ""}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}} *)
```

Search for your flag (I used #) using `Position` and then select all rows following that search

```
data[[Position[data, "#"][[1, 1]] + 1 ;;]]
(* {{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}} *)
```