# Import a table from a text file or string

Tags: import, data

[XYScan](http://rhig.physics.yale.edu/~ullrich/software/xyscan/) produces results in the following form (as *.txt):

```
# xyscan Version 3.3.1
# Date: Wed Sep 23 11:01:55 2015
# Scanned by: dimitris
# Source: /media/dimitris/E6B09AEDB09AC409/Documents and Settings/Dimitris/Documents/Prony_Math/F10.png
# Comment: 
# Format: x y -dx +dx -dy +dy
-0.20155    2.90211 0   0   0   0   
0.268734    2.92958 0   0   0   0   
0.802326    2.98451 0   0   0   0   
1.27261 3.03028 0   0   0   0   
1.78811 3.0669  0   0   0   0   
2.28553 3.10352 0   0   0   0   
2.50258 3.14014 0   0   0   0   
2.78295 3.18592 0   0   0   0   
-0.20155    2.74648 0   0   0   0   
0.268734    2.7831  0   0   0   0   
0.784238    2.82887 0   0   0   0   
1.27261 2.8838  0   0   0   0   
1.79716 2.92042 0   0   0   0   
2.27649 2.9662  0   0   0   0   
2.49354 2.98451 0   0   0   0   
2.79199 3.02113 0   0   0   0   
# EoF
```

I want *Mathematica* to read this *.txt file and given the above data to return the list

```
{{{-0.20155, 2.90211}, {0.268734, 2.92958}, {0.802326, 
   2.98451}, {1.27261, 3.03028}, {1.78811, 3.0669}, {2.28553, 
   3.10352}, {2.50258, 3.14014}, {2.78295, 3.18592}}, {{-0.20155, 
   2.74648}, {0.268734, 2.7831}, {0.784238, 2.82887}, {1.27261, 
   2.8838}, {1.79716, 2.92042}, {2.27649, 2.9662}, {2.49354, 
   2.98451}, {2.79199, 3.02113}}}
```

That is, discard the zeros and every 8 (horizontal) pairs of data consist a sngle list; i.e. here two lists.
How is it possible that?

**(EDIT)**

`FilePrint["C:\Users\Dimitris\Documents\Prony_Math\-49.txt"]` returns the file but also produces the error messages

> ```
> Syntax::stresc: Unknown string escape \U.
>
> Syntax::stresc: Unknown string escape \D.
>
> Syntax::stresc: Unknown string escape \D.
>
> Syntax::stresc: Unknown string escape \P.
> ```

In addition,

```
ReadList["C:\Users\Dimitris\Documents\Prony_Math\-49.txt", 
  Number, \!\(\*
ButtonBox["RecordLists",
BaseStyle->"Link",
ButtonData->"paclet:ref/RecordLists"]\) -> \!\(\*
ButtonBox["True",
BaseStyle->"Link",
ButtonData->"paclet:ref/True"]\)]

ReadList::intnm: Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 3 in ReadList[C:\Users\Dimitris\Documents\Prony_Math\-49.txt,Number,RecordLists->True]. >>
```

**(EDIT_2)**
I erased the first 6 lines of the *.txt file and modified the setting of the numbers as follows

```
-0.20155    2.90211     0   0   0   0   
0.268734    2.92958     0   0   0   0   
0.802326    2.98451     0   0   0   0   
1.27261     3.03028     0   0   0   0   
1.78811     3.0669      0   0   0   0   
2.28553     3.10352     0   0   0   0   
2.50258     3.14014     0   0   0   0   
2.78295     3.18592     0   0   0   0   
-0.20155    2.74648     0   0   0   0   
0.268734    2.7831      0   0   0   0   
0.784238    2.82887     0   0   0   0   
1.27261     2.8838      0   0   0   0   
1.79716     2.92042     0   0   0   0   
2.27649     2.9662      0   0   0   0   
2.49354     2.98451     0   0   0   0   
2.79199     3.02113     0   0   0   0
```

Still, the afforementioned error messages remain.

Comment: Ok, thanks again.

Comment: The "Unknown string escape" is a warning because you are using single backslashes in your file name. They should be escaped as double backslashes, or you can use forward slashes.  Fix the string, or you can do `Quiet@FilePrint`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50718/2079

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Your text data

```
str = "# xyscan Version 3.3.1
  # Date: Wed Sep 23 11:01:55 2015
  # Scanned by: dimitris
  # Source: /media/dimitris/E6B09AEDB09AC409/Documents and Settings/Dimitris/Documents/Prony_Math/F10.png
  # Comment: 
  # Format: x y -dx +dx -dy +dy
  -0.20155    2.90211 0   0   0   0   
  0.268734    2.92958 0   0   0   0   
  0.802326    2.98451 0   0   0   0   
  1.27261 3.03028 0   0   0   0   
  1.78811 3.0669  0   0   0   0   
  2.28553 3.10352 0   0   0   0   
  2.50258 3.14014 0   0   0   0   
  2.78295 3.18592 0   0   0   0   
  -0.20155    2.74648 0   0   0   0   
  0.268734    2.7831  0   0   0   0   
  0.784238    2.82887 0   0   0   0   
  1.27261 2.8838  0   0   0   0   
  1.79716 2.92042 0   0   0   0   
  2.27649 2.9662  0   0   0   0   
  2.49354 2.98451 0   0   0   0   
  2.79199 3.02113 0   0   0   0   
  # EoF";
```

or

```
str = Import["filename.txt", "Text"];
```

Remember to use double backslash for paths. As an example, evaluate `InputForm[$UserBaseDirectory]` and see how it looks.

### If you know which lines to remove

Read the details for [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html), [`Most`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Most.html) and [`Rest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rest.html).

```
data= Most@ImportString[str, "Table"][[7 ;;, {1, 2}]]
```

or

```
data = ImportString[str, "Table"][[7 ;; -2, {1, 2}]]
```

or

```
data = ImportString[str, "Table", HeaderLines -> 6][[;; -2, {1, 2}]]
```

> ```
> {{-0.20155, 2.90211}, {0.268734, 2.92958}, {0.802326, 2.98451}, {1.27261, 3.03028}, {1.78811, 3.0669}, {2.28553, 3.10352}, {2.50258, 3.14014}, {2.78295, 3.18592}, {-0.20155, 2.74648}, {0.268734, 2.7831}, {0.784238, 2.82887}, {1.27261, 2.8838}, {1.79716, 2.92042}, {2.27649, 2.9662}, {2.49354, 2.98451}, {2.79199, 3.02113}}
> ```

### Removing automatically all the lines that start with "#"

```
data = ImportString[
  StringTrim@
   StringDelete[str, Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ "#" ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfLine]]
  , "Table"][[All, {1, 2}]]
```

or

```
ImportString[
  StringDelete[str, 
   Shortest[StartOfLine ~~ "#" ~~ ___ ~~ EndOfLine] ~~ {"\n", "\r", "\r\n", ""}]
  , "Table"][[All, {1, 2}]]
```

[Other people have suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51015/10397) to load all the table and then select only the lines where the first cell is a number

```
Cases[ImportString[str, "Table"][[All,{1,2}]], {_?NumberQ, ___}];
```

### Visually inspect your data

```
TableForm[data, TableHeadings -> {Range[Length[data]], None}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Depending how yo do it you could change [`ImportString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImportString.html)`[str,"Table"]` for [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html)`[filename,"Table"]`

Read the options in the documentation for [`Table(.dat)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) and [`HeaderLines`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeaderLines.html).