# ReadList ignore comment lines?

Tags: import

Is there a way to make `ReadList` ignore certain "comment lines" (say, all lines that start with `#`, or in general all lines that match a string pattern)? This would be very useful for many types of files.

Comment: How are you using `ReadList`, reading in the whole file at once via `ReadList["file"]` or reading in a certain number of lines each time via `ReadList["file",types,n]`?

Comment: @JasonB Up to now I've done `ReadList["file"]`, but maybe `ReadList["file",types,n]` is more convenient to ignore comments?

Comment: So if you've read in the whole file using `ReadList["file"]`, then can't you simply remove the elements that match the pattern?

Comment: I don't think `ReadList` supports this.  Two ideas: 1. read the whole file as a string, filter the comments, convert the string to a stream, read from there 2. use `sed` to strip the comments, pipe the output to Mathematica (i.e. `ReadList["!sed ..."]` where you'll need to look up the correct arguments to `sed`).

Comment: possible dup : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50718/2079

Comment: @george2079 not a duplicate. The comments may be in the middle of the file.

Comment: I believe the answers over there address that.

Comment: @george2079 I would just point out that that answer uses `Import` to grab the whole file at once.  For large files (hundreds of megabytes), `Import` isn't practical and you have to resort to functions like `Read`.  I have a solution for this that reads in each line and applies your `ImportString@StringReplace.....` to it, but it's terribly slow.

Comment: The fastest thing likely is to use `sed` or `grep`. You can likely do that inline with something like `Import["!sed .... file" , ..]`.

Answer (score 5):

george2079's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/50722/9490) works great for ignoring comment lines, but it uses `Import` to read in the whole file at once.  Sometimes you have really large files that you can't `Import` in one go, you have to read them line by line.  Of course, for files where you can use *Import*, that will be faster because you are applying the test to the one big string instead of to each line one after the other.

So should it ever be needed, here is this slower method,

```
readTableIgnoreComments[fname_, comment_] := 
  Module[{stream, input, list},
   stream = OpenRead[fname];
   input = ReadLine[stream];
   list = Reap[
      While[input =!= EndOfFile,
        input = StringReplace[input, StartOfLine ~~ "#" ~~ __ -> ""];

        If[input =!= "",
         Sow[ImportString[input, "Table"][[1]]];
         ];
        input = ReadLine[stream];
        ];
      ][[2, 1]];
   Close[stream];
   list];
```

Say you have a data file, like [this one](http://pastebin.com/AFmW2BKQ).

```
readTableIgnoreComments["AFmW2BKQ.txt", "#"]

(*{{13.2177,6.30967,5.20213,5.93021},
{0.350016,13.4168,4.70314,6.16283},{3.61517,2.2622,13.4662,8.27606},
{9.82748,9.46039,0.894798,2.29597},{11.3524,5.98368,1.55609,2.20832},
{9.59792,3.70512,13.2309,12.156},{3.11005,11.4154,3.06589,11.9867},
{8.46262,9.44805,3.81819,12.8846},{13.7071,3.44253,4.13362,1.14301},
{0.353064,11.238,7.46061,7.04745},{5.24699,10.2069,4.79834,7.86099},
{7.90967,1.95548,6.44391,6.85132},{12.2419,7.94127,12.8604,10.4504},
{5.58408,6.49862,10.0892,10.2229},{5.5434,4.1264,13.0629,12.3711},
{5.35179,10.4674,1.39775,10.0056},{5.90251,12.3466,1.8162,5.9312},
{10.0368,3.42365,13.5114,10.938},{9.3393,4.55733,7.98305,1.01929},
{9.68279,9.00243,6.19094,0.482091},{8.86858,5.26325,2.35884,7.05454},
{4.37432,8.51505,3.90883,0.380504},{4.86367,9.19055,3.04116,10.9041},
{13.1294,7.39576,8.72494,1.72672},{12.5197,7.75693,9.2014,6.95952},
{8.95084,5.61415,12.6574,9.6697},{0.707468,3.96087,1.08438,10.7936},
{13.5005,3.14536,4.87679,6.00281},{6.74514,11.6024,2.23439,4.34998},
{7.34057,5.99825,1.02762,3.7478},{4.14484,6.2788,13.2522,4.1299},
{1.467,8.05903,8.09584,7.55979},{1.68094,2.35345,6.66405,4.4644},
{2.51467,8.88769,5.72158,6.80248},{13.6002,3.71197,2.81909,1.05188}}*)
```

As george2079 and Szabolcs pointed out, if you are lucky enough to be running an operating system with `sed`, then by far the fastest way to do this is to use `sed` to replace the commented lines,

```
readListIgnoreComments[fname_, comment_] := Module[{list},
  Run["sed -e '/^" <> comment <> ".*/d' " <> fname <> " > TEMP_" <> 
    fname];
  list = ReadList["TEMP_" <> fname];
  DeleteFile["TEMP_" <> fname];
  list
  ]
```