# Getting line number based on regexp match or Importing data with variable header size

Tags: import, regular-expressions

I have a text file with structure:

```
line 1 with some words
another line with some \\\ structure or ///
etc
until the last word line
lastline and now numbers which can be separated by anything
1232.232 12312.32
123.22
...
```

I would like to figure out where the data starts. The most obvious thing (but probably not the best one) would be to match the regexp '^lastline.+$' and return its line number. But this appears to be quite complicated, I have not found any method to get line numbers easily.

I am using the following to import the data:

```
Import[mytextfile, "Table", HeaderLines -> line_number_of_last_line]
```

There is a post [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50718/skip-header-lines-on-import) but it seems to assume that all the lines to skip have the comment sign `#` while I only know how the last line to skip looks like (the last line before data). So I would actually like a solution based on the logic read everything from the line folowing the regexp match.

Comment: Can we assume that there are no digits appearing anywhere in the first lines?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a procedural approach with streams to locate the last line since you know its format. This should be quicker than the regex approach for large files.

With

```
txt =
"line 1 with some words
another line with some \\\\\\ structure or ///
etc
until the last word line
lastline and now numbers which can be separated by anything
1232.232 12312.32
123.22";
```

Then the below will locate the `"lastline"` line number.  I use `StringToStream` but you would use `OpenRead` with the file path of the file. `StringStartsQ` can be swapped out for any test that complements the format of the last line.

```
header =
 Module[{stream, lastLine = 1},
  stream = StringToStream[txt];
  While[
   With[{rec = Read[stream, Record]},
    rec =!= EndOfFile && ! StringStartsQ[rec, "lastline"]
    ],
   lastLine++];
  Close[stream];
  lastLine
  ]
```

> ```
> 5
> ```

and

```
ImportString[txt, "Table", HeaderLines -> header]
```

> ```
> {{1232.23, 12312.3}, {123.22}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> So I would actually like a solution based on the logic read everything from the line folowing the regexp match.

You can skip the header and then import the rest of your file:

```
importData[stream_] := Module[{data},
   While[With[{rec = Read[stream, String]}, 
     rec =!= EndOfFile && ! StringStartsQ[rec, "lastline"]]];
   data = Import[stream, "Table"];
   Close[stream];
   data];
```

Now

```
txt = "line 1 with some words
another line with some \\\\\\ structure or ///
etc
until the last word line
lastline and now numbers which can be separated by anything
1232.232 12312.32
123.22";
stream = StringToStream[txt];

importData[stream]
```

> ```
> {{1232.23, 12312.3}, {123.22}}
> ```