# How to import files with headers?

Tags: import, data, text, streams, csv-format

R has excellent header supports such as [read.table](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) with header options. I don't want to mess up with text-processing or stream-processing. I am looking for a similar tool as in R because it saves a lot of tedious work.

**How can I import files with headers like 4 lines header where identifier on lines 1-2?**

---

**Example**

> Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96742826/Mathematica/henris_data_s3.csv"]
>
> [image]
>
> where four rows in the header and unique identifier is first row+second row like K3_INJ+GOPR. Numerical values start from the fifth row.

Comment: Btw I noticed that this file is a ragged, starting on the col position with empty column name 4526-16144, irritating. I think I will just preprocess the file first in my editor and then just read in Mathematica.

Comment: David Z in chat: "Ah, well I was going to say Map[{#[[1]] <> #[[2]], #[[3 ;;]]} &, list]. There should be a nicer way to do it with pattern substitution though, anyway."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will work with the ragged data array provided.

**Example 1**

> ```
> data = Import["henris_data_s3.csv"];
> vnames = Transpose[data[[{1, 2}]]];
> vnames[[99]]
>
> {"L1_INJ", "GWIR"}
> ```
>
> Above is the 'name' of the 99th record.
>
> ```
> Table[vdata[vnames[[i]]] = DeleteCases[Drop[Map[
>       Quiet[Check[Part[#, i], Null]] &, data], 4], Null],
>   {i, Length[vnames]}];
> ```
>
> This is the data in the 99th record.
>
> ```
> vdata[{"L1_INJ", "GWIR"}]
> ```
>
> {0, 0, 0, 581, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 0, 0, 0, ...
>
> Note, this method ignores columns without header information.

**Example 2**

> ```
> data = Import[
>    "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96742826/Mathematica/henris_data_s3.csv"];
> vnames = Transpose[data[[{1, 2}]]];
> Table[vdata[vnames[[i]]] = 
>    DeleteCases[Drop[Map[Quiet[Check[Part[#, i], Null]] &, data], 4], 
>     Null], {i, Length[vnames]}];
>
> vnames[[1]]
> vdata[vnames[[1]]]
> vdata[{"TIME", ""}]
> vdata[{"K3_PROD", "GOPR"}]
> ```
>
> [image]

Comment: I cannot understand `vdata[{"L1_INJ", "GWIR"}]`, can you explain what it is doing? How does `vdata[{"L1_INJ"}]` work if you have non-unique match (how is collision-resolution handled)?

Comment: `[{"L1_INJ", "GWIR"}` is a unique column identifier.  You can reformat it as you please.  The identifier is used as a data function argument in `vdata[...]`, which is populated in the `Table`.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain how to get data by name of the field? Cases such as `vdata[{TIME}]; vdata[{"TIME",}]; vdata[{"TIME"}]` are not working for me  -- I got it! `vdata[{"TIME", ""}]` works, testing! :D

Comment: Is there some easy way to match all entries with parts such as `PR` in the name? I am planning this `"regexp match all fields having 'PR' like 'FOPR' and 'GOPR'"`.

Comment: You can use `vnames2 = Select[vnames, MemberQ[StringMatchQ[#, "*PR*"], True] &]`

Comment: `vdata[{"FOPR", ""}]` returns a lot of zeros `{0, 0,..., 2200, 882, 436, ..., 0, ..., 7813812, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1582, 9632, 259, 301, 361, 301, 0, 0, ...` in the beginning, in-between and at the end. Plotting this kind of data is not actually as easy as I supposed: have to scale the axis, deal with zeros between the results -- not sure which plot to use here, perhaps scatter plot -- it is about production terms so they could also be connected, thinking.

Comment: Is there some easy way to do AND like `*IT` match and `*INJ` match? I do it currently this way `Injections = Select[vnames, MemberQ[StringMatchQ[#, "*INJ"], True] &]; InjectiosIT =  Select[Injections, MemberQ[StringMatchQ[#, "*IT"], True] &]; InjectiosIR =  Select[Injections, MemberQ[StringMatchQ[#, "*IR"], True] &]`.

Answer (score 2):

[Leonid](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18577337#18577337) provided the following demo in chat: the basic idea is to use R's read.table header management before coming back to Mathematica.

```
file = URLSave["http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/TechCrunchcontinentalUSA.csv"];

Needs["RLink`"]
InstallR[];
RSet["testfile", file];
REvaluate["testdata <- read.table(testfile, header=TRUE)"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to this question with a header of many lines and unique identifier specified by many lines. I am trying to create discussion about this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18556146#18556146).

**Alternative solution with *ix tools**

> 1. Edit the original file to simpler form with instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26857592/164148) so simplified datadump [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/96742826/K1K2.csv)
> 2. and now read the simplified CSV into Mathematica where only first row has the unique identifier, wuola!

**Mathematica solution, perhaps?**

> 1. [Skip header lines on import](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50718/skip-header-lines-on-import)
> 2. [ReadList with header and foot lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44229/readlist-with-header-and-foot-lines)
> 3. [Stream CSV or TSV files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3890/stream-csv-files)
> 4. [Reading specific entries from a CSV file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51004/reading-specific-entries-from-a-csv-file)

**Puzzles**

> **String manipulation**
>
> > **I. combine rows 1-2**
> >
> > > [image]
> > >
> > > ```
> > > data = {{a, a, c}, {i, j, k}, {1, 2, 3}};
> > > Transpose[data]
> > > ```
>
> **Stream manipulation**
>
> > **I. specify the header so that ignore rows 3-4 and make rows 1-2 into an identifier**

Comment: @Öskå Chris's answer does not return correct output :/ Alerted him now in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18562828#18562828).