# In a Function, how to Ensure Code Runs Prior to an Abort

Tags: function-construction, streams

Is there a way to set aside some code in a function that will be triggered to run if the evaluation of the function is aborted by a user? Specifically, I have a function that has to open a log file to write to, but the algorithm in the function in many cases doesn't finish so it has to be aborted:

```
f[]:= Module[{},
    logstream = OpenWrite["logfile.txt"];
    (*  algorithm that often doesn't finish  *)
    Close[logstream];
];
```

Is there some way to ensure within the function that the `Close[logstream]` gets run even if the function gets manually aborted in the loop? (Or is there some other mechanism to achieve the same thing?) I've come across `AbortProtect[]` which seems like it should be useful here, but I don't think it's applicable in this situation.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365794/reliable-clean-up-in-mathematica) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1602/resource-management-in-mathematica). In fact, your question is probably a dupe of the latter.