# ToExpression processing errors

Tags: syntax, expression-manipulation

Is their a way to get a more comprehensive return value when running `ToExpression`?

For example when I run `ToExpression["a[b[c,1],2],3]"]` all I get from the output is `$Failed` when I'm looking for something more like `Expression "a[b[c,1],2],3]" has no opening "[".`

Comment: Look at `SyntaxQ` and `SyntaxLength` - in particular, if the latter returns > length of string, it implies the partial expression is correct syntactically but incomplete....

Comment: @ciao Tell me if I am missing something but it appears that neither return an error message for example `Expression "a[b[c,1],2],3]" has no opening "[".`  `ToExpression` prints much more descriptive errors.

Comment: They will not return an error message for those, nor should they: `SyntaxQ` will return `False`, indicating an invalid expression, `SyntaxLength` will return `11`, indicating the expression up to `a[b[c,1],2]` is valid. If you want to generate messages, you'll need to build that yourself before submitting to `ToExpression` (and `$SyntaxHandler` is regrettably not in play, `ToExpression` does not use it).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One way would be to redirect all messages issued by `ToExpression` to a string-stream.  Here is an example of that approach, with minimal error-checking:

```
Needs["Developer`"]

interpret[str_String] :=
  Module[{s = StreamToString[], r, m}
  , Block[{$Messages = {s}}, r = ToExpression[str, InputForm, HoldComplete]]
  ; m = StringFromStream[s]
  ; Close[s]
  ; <| "result" -> r, "messages" -> m |>
  ]
```

It returns an association with the result and any messages returned by the interpretation.  The result is held in unevaluated form when the interpretation is successful.

Here are some examples:

```
interpret["1+"]

(* <| "result" -> $Failed
    , "messages" -> "ToExpression::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed ."
    |>
*)

interpret["1+1"]

(* <| "result" -> HoldComplete[1+1], "messages" -> "" |> *)

interpret["a[b[c,1],2],3]"]

(* <| "result" -> $Failed
    , "messages" -> "ToExpression::sntx: Invalid syntax in or before \"a[b[c,1],2],3]\"."
    |>
*)
```

The exhibited function makes no attempt to handle abort or other non-local exits from `ToExpression`.  Should one of those occur then the return value and messages will be lost, and the string-stream will not be closed.  If a bullet-proof function is required, then more elaborate error-handling will be required (perhaps using `CheckAll` or the like -- see [Resource Management in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1602/142) for suggestions).

**Update**

As requested in a comment, here is a different version of `interpret` with better error handling should `ToExpression` fail catastrophically:

```
interpret2[str_String] :=
  withSetup[
    { s = StreamToString[]; Close[s]
    , r = Block[{$Messages = {s}}, ToExpression[str, InputForm, HoldComplete]]
    , m = StringFromStream[s]
    }
  , <| "result" -> r, "messages" -> m |>
  ]
```

It uses the `CheckAll`-based function `withSetup` defined in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/48493/142) to ensure that the string-stream is released even if `ToExpression` takes a non-local exit.

Comment: I added a bounty in hopes you might create a more bullet proof solution.  It isn't clear to me add 1st glance what you mean by `CheckAll` I'm just now reading.

Comment: I added an example of what I meant by "more elaborate error-handling".  This is probably about as bullet-proof as we can get in high-level _Mathematica_ code, without access to the internal C++ parsing code.