# Check does not interrupt evaluation of the expression when a Message is emitted

Tags: message-coding, error-trapping

On the surface, `Check` looks like a good method to use when you need to abort the evaluation of an expression whenever a `Message` is emitted. Unfortunately, as the following code demonstrates, the evaluation of the expression is completed after a `Message` has occurred.

```
(* the test message *)
Test::wrpt = "Negative point at `1`";

dat = RandomReal[1, 500];

(* without Check *)
woCheck = MapIndexed[
   If[# < 0, 
     Message[Test::wrpt, #2[[1]]]; Unevaluated[Sequence[]], 
     #] &,
   {-1}~Join~dat];

(* with Check *)
res = {};
Check[
 MapIndexed[
  If[# < 0, 
    Message[Test::wrpt, #2[[1]]]; Unevaluated[Sequence[]], 
    res = {res, #}; #] &,
  {-1}~Join~dat],
 $Failed
 ]
 (* Test::wrpt: Negative point at 1
  $Failed
 *)
```

But, when comparing the two

```
woCheck == Flatten@res
(* True *)
```

This implies, that for long running computations `Check` is not a good solution to abort a computation if an error `Message` is emitted. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple method for accomplishing this is to have `Message` `Throw` an error when it is called, interrupting the current execution. Here is a replacement for `Check` which does that, with the same calling signature:

```
ClearAll[InterruptingCheck]
SetAttributes[InterruptingCheck, HoldAll]

InterruptingCheck[expr_, failexpr_, msgs : {___MessageName } : {}] :=
 Internal`InheritedBlock[{Message, $msgFlag},
      (* Module localizes tag while not polluting the global namespace *)
      Module[{ tag },
      Unprotect[Message];
      (* 
      Attach hook to message, where failexpr is thrown after the 
      first Message is raised. msgFlag is used to prevent recursion,
      so that when msg is called the original def is used.
      *)
      msg : Message[m_, ___] /; ! TrueQ[$msgFlag] := Block[{$msgFlag = True},
     msg;
     If[Length@msgs == 0 || MemberQ[msgs, m], Throw[failexpr, tag]]];
     Catch[expr, tag]
  ]
 ]

(* With Leonid's suggestion, this now works correctly. *)
InterruptingCheck[expr_, failexpr_, msgGroup_String] := 
 Hold[msgGroup] /. $MessageGroups /. 
  Hold[messages_List] :> InterruptingCheck[expr, failexpr, messages]
```

**\begin{Edit}**

My original code for the supplying a [message group](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24MessageGroups.html) failed to work correctly. The fix is shown above.  It works by replacing `msgGroup` with the appropriate list of messages, but using `Hold` to prevent them from being replaced by their string equivalents. (That is part of the reason for the `HoldAll` attribute being used here, to begin with.) Then, the held `messages` are extracted from `Hold` and inserted into `InterruptingCheck` still held because of `HoldAll`.

**\end{Edit}**

When applied to the example in the question,

```
res2 = {};
InterruptingCheck[
 MapIndexed[
  If[# < 0, 
    Message[Test::wrpt, #2[[1]]]; Unevaluated[Sequence[]], 
    res2 = {res2, #}; #] &,
  dat[[;; 10]]~Join~{-1}~Join~dat],
 $Failed,
     {Test::wrpt}
     ]
     (* Test::wrpt: Negative point at 11
     $Failed
 *)
```

and `res2` is

```
{0.288047, 0.026642, 0.361008, 0.28977, 0.573743, 
0.272747, 0.937062, 0.330572, 0.192807, 0.916764}
```

showing that it did stop execution at after the tenth element in the data.

Comment: I was in the middle of writing an answer... ;-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard sorry. Still post it, I wasn't planning on accepting this until I had heard from others, too.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Unless of course, that was sarcasm. Then we need to get the sarcasm highlighter up and running.

Comment: No, it was basically the same thing.  IMHO you should tag the Throw and Catch.  Not sarcasm.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard good suggestion. Fixed.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/how-to-abort-on-any-message-generated) seems related?

Comment: @Rojo definitely related, and some of the solutions would be effective here, also. I had forgotten about that question ...

Comment: @Rojo upon re-reading that question, I think they're asking for different things: `Abort` when a message is emitted vs. stop execution within `Check` when a message is emitted as `Check` appears like it should do this, but doesn't.

Comment: One problem is that `Message` is called even inside `Quiet`.  Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1545/12)?  You could try using the 'message handler'.

Comment: @Szabolcs which means it behaves in exactly the same manner as `Check` does with `Quiet`. And, no I had not seen that when I wrote this. Otherwise I probably would have used it.

Comment: @rcollyer Note that your second definition of `InterruptingCheck` will never work as intended (which may or may not be a problem, I don't know), since the code `msgGroup /. $MessageGroups` will not execute (as `InterruptingCheck` is `HoldAll`), and therefore, will have the head `ReplaceAll`, and will not match the pattern for this argument (`{___MessageName }`).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin you are correct, nor does `Evaluate[msgGroup /. $MessageGroups]` as the messages are replaced by their string equivalents. I'll have to think about how to work around that ...

Comment: @rcollyer I'd use the "injector pattern" - this is a job for it: `InterruptingCheck[expr_, failexpr_, msgGroup_String] := Hold[msgGroup] /. $MessageGroups /. Hold[messages_List] :> InterruptingCheck[expr, failexpr, messages]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Beautiful! Did I mention I am not a fan of the hold attributes? They're tough to get right.

Comment: @rcollyer Agree.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @rcollyer Welcome. +1.