# Dealing with errors and resuming the code after one

Tags: warning-messages, debugging, message-coding, error-tracking

How can I write my *Mathematica* code so that it resumes at a specific place if any `Message` is displayed during the execution of an expression? For example, in Visual Basic for Applications there's `on error resume next`, or `on error goto`. I'd like also to be able to log the issue in a list so I can reproduce and correct the problem later.

Comment: You've looked at `Check`, `Catch`,`Throw` and `CheckAbort` ? [ Whispers: oh and there is also `Goto` ].

Comment: Check [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1545/109) too

Comment: Check is what are I need, and the other possibilities are interesting also, thanks.

Comment: @image_doctor as your comment answers the question can you please write a proper answer ?

Comment: @image_doctor, maybe you can answer the question now? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Check`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html):

> Check[*expr*, *failexpr*]   evaluates *expr*, and returns the result,
>   unless messages were generated, in which case it evaluates and returns
>   *failexpr*.
>
> Check[*expr*, *failexpr*, {s<sub>1</sub>::t<sub>1</sub>,
>   s<sub>2</sub>::<sub>2</sub>, …}]   checks only for the specified
>   messages.
>
> Check[*expr*, *failexpr*, *"name"*]   checks only for messages in the
>   named message group.

[`CheckAbort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CheckAbort.html):

> CheckAbort[*expr*, *failexpr*] evaluates *expr*, returning *failexpr* if an abort occurs.

Other information that may prove useful:

- [`$MessageList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$MessageList.html)
- [How to abort on any message generated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1512/121)
- [Check does not interrupt evaluation of the expression when a Message is emitted](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5534/121)
- [Prepend Information to Warning Messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8215/121)
- [How to catch complete error message information, including the message text as it would be printed?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20367/121)