# Exception/Error handling using returns codes

Tags: warning-messages, error-trapping

There is good explanation available for error handling on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560116/best-practices-in-error-reporting-mathematica) and similar [links](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/634/error-checking-and-trapping-techniques-with-throw-and-catch). Here there is information on handling inappropriate input arguments and handling unprocessed functions using `$Failed`. But it is much of incomplete because I want to catch error message and according to that display some specific message. For example if I get

```
Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^n does not converge on {1,\[Infinity]}. >>
```

Than I want to display some specific message in words which is possible if I can capture this message and extract from it or if Mathematica returns some error code associated.

Is there some better technique available than just using `$Failed` everywhere ?

Comment: Related: [(1512)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1512/121), [(8215)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8215/121) [(20367)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20367/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks for closely related link, I am going through it now.

Comment: I added two more links in the comment above.  I think ``Internal`AddHandler["Message", . . .]`` may be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: [this link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19324/interrupting-package-evaluation-handling-error) is also related

Comment: Blackbird, have you gone through those links yet, especially 20367?  If you have and a question remains please clarify it and I'll attempt to answer.  If not I may close this question as a duplicate, or if you prefer you can summarize your solution in an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Please give me time for 3-4 days..I have some office work pending.

Comment: I personally use exceptions where I put enough information in the arguments of `Throw` to find out which error it was. No time right now do decribe this in more detail, but it is a logical extension of the exception-based method I described in the link you cited. You can also look at the source code of `RLink` to see this applied in practice.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard:can you please contribute an answer here as you were offering to.

Comment: Blackbird, I just found your request again; I know I read it but I forgot.  Sorry.  Do you still need help with this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Actually I was exploring error code handling, than I got this question. But it will be great if you could include something worthy to make this post a learning place for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

This is an attempt to answer my question.
Using the links suggested in comments I came up with following steps. Let there be some sample function 'sam'.

```
$MessagePrePrint = Sow;
    Sam[a_, b_] := 
     Reap[Module[{}, {1/0, LinearSolve[{{a}}, {{b}}]}]; $MessageList]
```

Making use of Mathlink,

```
    link = LinkLaunch[First[$CommandLine] <> " -mathlink"]
    LinkWrite[link, EnterTextPacket[Sam[0, 1]]]
    t = LinkRead[link]
```

This gives

```
ReturnPacket[EnterTextPacket[{{Power::infy,LinearSolve::nosol},{{1/0}}}]]
```

Collecting information out of above,

```
l = Level[t, 3][[1]]
```

returns=    `{Power::infy,LinearSolve::nosol}`

Using replace ,`ty=l/.{Power::infy->1,LinearSolve::nosol->2}`

Now a separate function can be written to pass this list to and place custom messages.

```
Pr[a_] := Module[{}, { a, "->",
   If[a === 1, "No solution available",
    If[a === 2, "Illegal division", If[a === 3, "Sample error "]]]}]
```

Calling it using `Table[Pr[ty[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[ty]}]`

gives `{{1, "->", "No solution available"}, {2, "->", "Illegal division"}}`

Actually @Mr.Wizard's answer on one of the link, answers with lot less hustle but this way I learned one more thing.
If is not really a professional solution and bit childish lacking professional approach.

I would request if someone would like to amend/update this question, please go ahead. Suggestion are most welcome.

Comment: One thing I wanted to point out is that if Reap/Sow is not used in that case only the last error is captured by `EnterTextPacket`. Rest above it are ignored. As far as replacement rules are concerned they can be implemented as ruleset.

Comment: One more way I found out to collect messages is used Trace[expr,Message[ ___ ]]. It is in documentation.