# How to switch off all messages?

Tags: warning-messages, message-coding

How can I want to switch off **all** messages in a *Mathematica* session? `Quiet[expr]` allows me to evaluate `expr` without messages. `Off[msg]` switches off the particular message `msg`.

Is there a command that, once evaluated, guarantees that all further evaluations will run quietly? (Unless some messages are turned back `On`)

Comment: It is not clear why `Quiet` isn;t what you are looking for. Do you mean that you want the first message displayed but then no others? Can you please clarify.

Comment: Why do you want to turn off *all* messages?  Perhaps what you want is not to turn them off, just to prevent them from being printed (which is technically not the same thing).  Try `$Messages = {}`.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I don't want any messages. I want a command that sets the Kernel in a state such that further evaluations won't output messages.

Comment: @Szabolcs What's the difference between turning messages off and prevent them from being printed?

Comment: @becko ok. in that case suggestions made in the answer and comments should help you

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks. `$Messages = {}` works, as does ybeltukov's answer. But, as you say, both only prevent messages from being printed (right?).

Comment: @becko In practice, yes.  I hope my answer clarifies this.  The problem with `$Pre = Quiet` is that you can't use it in a script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, note that turning off messages is technically not the same thing as not printing them.  You can avoid printing messages by removing the output channel they're being sent to:

```
$Messages = {}
```

Restore the previous behaviour using  `$Messages = $Output`, provided that you haven't changed `$Output`.

But this won't *turn messages off*, it will only avoid printing them.  Here's the transcript for one particular example which shows the effect of turning off messages, as opposed to not printing them:

```
In[1]:= boo::mess = "Boo message"
Out[1]= "Boo message"

In[2]:= boo[] := (Message[boo::mess]; 1)

In[3]:= boo[]

During evaluation of In[3]:= boo::mess: Boo message

Out[3]= 1

In[4]:= Check[boo[], "error"]

During evaluation of In[4]:= boo::mess: Boo message

Out[4]= "error"

In[5]:= Off[boo::mess]

In[6]:= Check[boo[], "error"]
Out[6]= 1

In[7]:= On[boo::mess]
        $Messages = {};

In[9]:= Check[boo[], "error"]    
Out[9]= "error"
```

(Make sure that you evaluate these as separate inputs (cells).  Some only have an effect on subsequent inputs, but not on separate code within the same input.)

Notice that turning off the message had an effect on `Check`, but simply preventing printing it did not.  It has effects on various other documented and [undocumented](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1545/12) parts of Mathematica as well, such as the debugging tools ("Break on messages" feature).

`Quiet[expr]` does actually prevent the messages generated by `expr` from reaching any code outside of the `Quiet[...]`, just like turning `Off` the messages.

---

Here's a different idea:  if your program is written in a script (`.m` file), then you can run it on a single input line using `Get`.  This means that you can capture all generated messages with [`$MessageList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24MessageList.html).  Then you can create a [`message group`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24MessageGroups.html) for them which will allow you to easily toggle them using `Off` and `On`.  If a new, unexpected message shows up at some point, it will still get printed, which might be good or bad depending on your application.

Comment: +1 Actually, a script is precisely what I have in mind. It would be nice if I could turn all messages off, not just a group. Btw, how do I create a message group (by the [] it seems you wanted to include a link or something)? And couldn't I create a message group including *all* messages?

Comment: It seems you were trying to include a link. I tried to edit your post to fix it, but it didn't work... I think the `$`s are messing up the links.

Comment: @becko Thanks for noticing the problem.  I'll fix it.  I rejected your edit the first time because it showed wrong in the diff view (possibly because of the dollar sign again), then because I was in the process of trying to fix it.  There are problems with dollar signs sometimes :-(

Comment: Ok. I did one last edit. I leave in your hands.

Comment: @becko I think I managed to fix it now ...

Comment: Yes. It's fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can add `Quiet` to all evaluated expressions by

```
$Pre = Quiet
```

```
1/0
```

> No messages

Comment: it seems not turning off such message as with `NumberForm[2.77*^25, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]`