# Detecting changes of variables' values

Tags: eventhandler

Is it possible to detect (and create a trigger for) an event when any of the variables defined in the notebook changes its value (for any reason)?

I need to know which variable got changed and what the new value is.

Here are some details:

I have a client-server application, where the client is my Mathematica notebook. I also have a Java layer in between. The server runs MongoDB database and when any client modifies it, the server sends updates to all other clients. Specifically, to the Java layer. The job of the Java layer is to keep an up-to-date local copy of the database, and to relay all updates to the Mathematica client.

```
Needs["JLink`"]
InstallJava[];
ReinstallJava[ClassPath -> "/Users/verse/Desktop/java-ddp-client.jar"];
LoadJavaClass["java.lang.System"];
LoadJavaClass["java.lang.Object"];
LoadJavaClass["java.lang.reflect.Array"];
LoadJavaClass["com.wolfram.jlink.JLinkClassLoader"];
LoadJavaClass["me.kutrumbos.examples.MessageHandler"];
```

url = "localhost"; port = 3000;
client = JavaNew["me.kutrumbos.DdpClient", url, 
   MakeJavaObject[port]];
observer = 
  JavaNew["me.kutrumbos.examples.ObservableDdpClientObserver"];
collections = {};
onCollectionUpdate[msg_] := 
  Module[{}, collections = observer@getJSONObjectsList["test"];];

observer@addMessageHandler[
   ImplementJavaInterface["me.kutrumbos.examples.MessageHandler", 
    "update" -> "onCollectionUpdate"]];

client@addObserver[observer];
(*ShowJavaConsole[];*)
client@connect[];

In this example, variable `collections` gets updated by the Java layer every time there is a change in the underlying database. It does not happen through the `Set` command inside the notebook. I need to know when this does happen and I need to properly update other variables.

Conversely, when any of the relevant variables change inside the notebook, I need to be able to update the database on the server using an API request. To send such a request, I need to know which variable has changed and what the new value is.

Comment: See the help for `Dynamic` there are many examples there.

Comment: have you seen `Monitor[]`?

Comment: @bill s, would you mind pointing me to the part that you had in mind? I've read the `Dynamic` tutorial, but didn't see a way to detect the changes. My understanding was that `Dynamic` does the updating itself, but does not allow for trigger actions. @belisarius, I think `Monitor` won't work for my purposes -- it only shows the current value of a variable while a given expression is evaluated, but in my case there is no evaluation. Variables may be changed at any time by an external process (server update).

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you want to happen? Present a specific scenario (preferably with code) so that we can see what you are trying to do?

Comment: @user6236 I have marked this question as too broad, because it is not clear what you are trying to do.  Because of the way that `Dynamic` is implemented it may be useful or entirely *useless* for your task.  There are other methods such as `ScheduledTask` that you should look at too.  But outlining *all* of these methods is IMHO too extensive.

Comment: Ah, I see you were already adding those details.  Thank you.

Comment: @user6236 Presumably onCollectionUpdate[msg_] is being called and collections is changing its value.  Why can't you just add more code to this function?

Comment: @Ymareth I can, but that's only one of the places where the variables can change -- they can also change within the notebook.

Comment: @user6236 But lets nail down cases.  This is the only place the java code can change the state of the notebook?

Comment: @user6236 Also your code above has collections = observer@getJSONObjectsList["test"];  This does use Set.  So I'm puzzled why my answer below didn't work.

Comment: @Ymareth I think I was able to isolate all the places where the variables change, and applied your solution. Works so far! Thanks you.

Comment: @user6236 - Welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something along the lines of ...

```
a /: Set[a,x_]:=((OwnValues[a]={HoldPattern[a]:>x}; Print[{"a was set to:",x}]); a)

a = 1 prints {a was set to:,1}

a on its own is now 1.
```

Extends what set does with an additional action which here is Print but ,in principle, could be anything.

Comment: Be aware that this definition will not catch many of the ways that the value of `a` can change.  I shall wait to see what the OP intends before voting on this.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case this method won't work because the variables are updated by the Java layer, and not by the `Set` command.

Comment: @user6236 I see the question has changed quite a bit since it was first posted.  How soon after the collection has changed do you need to trigger your process? (emphasis on "need").

Comment: @Ymareth I basically need to have consistently synchronized data across all clients and the server. This requires reacting to all the changes as quickly as possible.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to get a handle on if you "need" mathematica to respond to every update or you "can live with" the state gathered say every 100ms?  Essentially can you reverse the problem and just have mathematica go look every 100ms?

Comment: @Ymareth Yes, I thought of using polling, but my client-side logic is already very CPU-intensive, and using polling very detrimental to the performance. I was very much hoping to find an event-driven way of detecting the changes.

Comment: That would be nice but if its a problem you don't have why add to your woes on a Friday.  Mathematica asking "has this changed?" 10 times a second is not going to add to you CPU load in any significant way.

Comment: @Ymareth I did try it -- my laptop can't handle it, even when I parallelize my main application logic.

Comment: If anybody is willing to investigate or reverse engineer this, take a look at [``Internal`Handlers[]``](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1545/12), and see "ValueChange"-related ones are useful.  I never dug into this and I don't even know if it works or not.

Answer (score 9):

There is `ValueFunction`, documented [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Experimental/ref/ValueFunction.html).

It allows detecting value changes for given symbols.

For example,

```
In[1]:= Experimental`ValueFunction[x] := Print["x changed"]

In[2]:= x = 6

During evaluation of In[10]:= x changed

Out[2]= 6
```

Comment: Why doesn't this have any votes!? +1!

Comment: From the docs: "`ValueFunction` takes account of all ways that the value of a symbol can be changed, not just `Set`." However, even a cursory examination shows that this is totally wrong. So much for "documentation"!

Comment: @OleksandrR. How did you break it?

Comment: Well, it failed with pretty much everything I tried. It seems only to pay attention to `OwnValues`. Yet, changing even these by any slightly non-standard method (e.g. manipulating `OwnValues` directly) doesn't trigger it. Nor does changing a part of a value. It would be interesting to know what scenarios it does actually cover.

Comment: @Oleksandr I'm not surprised that direct modification of `OwnValues` doesn't work, at that is expressly outside of "normal" operation.  Things like `Increment` and `AppendTo` do work, but I am sad to see that as you say assignments to parts do not.  Nevertheless I think this still has value.

Comment: @Oleksandr Also changes by `Block` and related (`Table`, `Plot`, etc.) are caught.  Are you aware of any *other* things that fail besides direct `OwnValues` manipulation (which again I'm OK with) and `Part` assignments?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard well, `Increment` etc. should of course work because these are implemented in terms of `Set` anyway. It's encouraging to know that `Block` and implicit equivalents are handled properly; I didn't get as far as trying this. Loading a dump file containing the monitored symbol also triggers it. So perhaps it isn't as useless as I first thought. I just gave up in disgust after finding that only `OwnValues` are monitored (though these are far from the only type of values), and even then it doesn't catch everything. If the documentation were more realistic, I wouldn't have objected.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The fact that it catches `Block`-induced temporary value changes might actually be counterproductive in some cases.  I have never used this in practice, so I don't know how well it would work for various tasks.  If you use it, I'd be curious to see how (just leave a comment here with the link).

Comment: Fun..I don't sure you have seen the ``?ValueTrack`*``.But hard use ``GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions`` to dig their usage..