# Converting expression into string without evaluating it

Tags: evaluation, hold, conversion

How can one convert a Mathematica expression into a string without the expression being evaluated first? I tried using `Hold`, but it returns `Hold[expr]`, instead of `expr`. Is there any way to get just the expression?

For example, I have a variable `var = 5`, and I need to assign the *name* of `var` to another variable, so that `var2 = "var"`. How can I do this?

My actual use case is this:

I am trying to synchronize my mathematica variables with certain fields in an external database. Every time the external database is updated, I call on a function that is supposed to update my corresponding Mathematica variables. It takes in a list of mappings like `{var1 -> "field1", var2 -> "field2"}`, and its role is to access the external database, look up the value in `"field1"`, and assign it to `var1`, then look up the value in `"field2"` and assign it to `var2`. The number of variables in the mapping (and their names) can be arbitrary.

The problem is that I need those `var1` and `var2` variables to be passed as variable *names*, not values, so that I can assign them inside the function. I do the assignment using

`Do[ 
     i[[1]]->i[[2]]/.remoteData,
     {i,mappings}
]`

where `remoteData = {"field1"->"value of field 1", "field2" -> "value of field 2"}`. I need `i[[1]]` to stand for `var1`, not for its value. I tried setting the attribute `SetAttributes[fn,HoldAll]` but that didn't help.

The result that I am looking for is `var1 = "value of field 1"`, `var 2 = "value of field 2"`.

Comment: This is a duplicate I believe so I shall not post an answer.  I think the simplest is `MakeBoxes[var]`, but how you get `var` into that expression will be the issue.  What is your *actual* use for this?

Comment: What I mean is, you could of course just type in `"var"` so presumably you are working with some list of Symbol names or the like that you need to manipulate.  Please describe the situation and your goals.

Comment: Other alternatives include `SymbolName @ Unevaluated[var]` and `ToString @ HoldForm[var]` and each of these may be useful, again depending on your actual needs.  I await your clarification.

Comment: The key is `Unevaluated`.  As MrW said, you can use something similar to `ToString@Unevaluated[1+1]`.  It gives `"1 + 1"`.  Juggling unevaluated expressions is likely to get complicated though ...

Comment: In my case `Unevaluated` makes it impossible to look up the value of `i[[1]]`, which is `var1`. So I do need the first level of evaluation that replaces `i[[1]]` with `var1`, I just don't want Mathematica to further replace `var1` with its value.

Comment: @user6236 Let me make sure I understand what you are doing.  You have a table with headings in a text file.  You want to read this table in and assign the columns to certain variables.  You want to do this based on some mapping of the form `"heading-name" -> variable` that your code takes as input.  Is this correct?

Comment: You said "It takes in a list of mappings like ..." -- where did `mappings` come from and is it wrapped in `Hold` now to prevent evaluation?

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes, that's correct. @MrW, I define a function `fn[mappings_]:= Do[ i[[1]]->i[[2]]/.remoteData, {i,mappings} ]`, and set `SetAttributes[fn,HoldAll]`.

Comment: Also, when I call on `fn` I myself decide which variable I want to map to which fields in the db. So `mappings` are defined by the end-user.

Comment: @user6236 Okay, what is the source of the expression you are passing to `fn` (as parameter `mappings`)?

Comment: Okay, I think I was focusing on the wrong item.  What is the source of `remoteData`?  We (or at least I) need to see the bigger picture here.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22data+table+manipulation%22) is not an answer, but it's related and might be interesting.  @Mr.Wizard I believe I could answer this is it's reopened ...

Comment: @Szabolcs Waiting for you.

Comment: I have a Java layer that I described in my previous question here (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41884/detecting-changes-of-variables-values), which updates `remoteData` whenever the server informs it of any changes. The data on the server is stored in MongoDB in JSON format, and then imported as a standard Mathematica list using `ImportString[..., "JSON"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like I should have used `HoldForm` instead of `Hold`.

Here is my current solution that does the job:

```
SetAttributes[fn,HoldAll];

fn[mappings_]:= ReleaseHold[Apply[Set, HoldForm[mappings]/.remoteData, {2}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, this is what you are asking:

You have a table with headings in a text file. You want to read this table in and assign the columns to certain variables. You want to do this based on some mapping of the form "heading-name" -> variable that your code takes as input.

First of all, personally I feel uneasy about programmatically manipulating variable names, but I know that many people disagree with this ... If I were doing this myself, I'd choose to retrieve the columns based on some name stored as a string (e.g. using replacement rules), but not actually assign to variables corresponding to this name.  There are fewer things that can go wrong, e.g. variables won't accidentally get overwritten.

---

That said, here's how to do what you asked for.  Here's a example table stored in a string.  You'll have a file instead.

```
table = 
 "one  two  three
   1    2    3
   4    5    6
   7    8    9"
```

These are the mappings.  Variable names are stored as strings to prevent evaluation:

```
mapping = {"var1" -> "one", "var2" -> "two", "var3" -> "three"}
```

We'll use this function to assign to variables:

```
set[s_String, v_] := ToExpression[s, InputForm, Function[x, x = v, {HoldFirst}]]
```

The code:

```
data = ImportString[table, "Table"]
values = mapping[[All, 2]] /. (First[#] -> Rest[#] &) /@ Transpose[data]
MapThread[set, {mapping[[All, 1]], values}];
```

Now the variables are set to the values read from the table, based on the mappings we defined:

```
var1

(* ==> {1,4,7} *)
```

The key was using the third argument to [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ToExpression.html), which allows manipulating an expression converted from a string *before* it gets evaluated.

---

However, as I said at the beginning, I would stop at creating the mapping `(First[#] -> Rest[#] &) /@ Transpose[data]` and using it to reference columns by their names.

---

**EDIT:**  Per the OP's request, here's how to do it without storing the variable names as strings.  In this case we need to store the mapping inside `Hold` to prevent evaluating the variables.

```
mapping = Hold[var1 -> "one", var2 -> "two", var3 -> "three"]

ReleaseHold[Set @@@ (mapping /. (First[#] -> Rest[#] &) /@ Transpose[data])];
```

Slightly simpler with a different syntax for the mapping:

```
mapping = Hold[var1 = "one", var2 = "two", var3 = "three"];
ReleaseHold[ mapping /. (First[#] -> Rest[#] &) /@ Transpose[data] ];
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I did consider passing variable names as strings to my function, but that didn't look like native Mathematica code. There must be a way to actually pass the variables themselves, but not evaluate them right away, since many built-in functions are able to do this.

Comment: @user6236 The whole idea of assigning to variables progammatically based on their name makes me feel uneasy, so at this point I stopped being bothered by what looks "native" or "beautiful" ... but yes, it's possible, if you keep the mapping inside a `Hold`.  Otherwise not.

Comment: could you please clarify how one can use `Hold` to achieve the desired outcome? The problem I encountered was that if I put `Hold` around `i[[1]]` inside my function, it is not replaced with `var1`.

Comment: @user6236 OK, I updated the post.  Can you please choose a display name other than the auto-generated user98765-style name?  I don't understand your last comment completely, so let me know if this is not what you're looking for.