# How do I get parantheses into an exponent inside a string

Tags: string-manipulation, labeling

I would like to write $R^{(2)}$ and use this as a FrameLabel. This means that I specifically want () around the 2 in the exponent.
I've tried using

```
ToExpression["$R^{(2)}$", TeXForm]
```

but this produces only the 2 in the exponent with no parantheses.
Thank you for any help and merry christmas!

Comment: `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, R^"(2)"}]`

Comment: Interesting, the answer here:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140336/how-to-convert-texform-to-string-via-toexpression-without-it-being-evaluated-in

does not seem to solve the problem (note: instead of converting to string, convert to traditional form to preserve superscript). Mathematica still removes the brackets. There needs to be a direct way of converting from `TeXForm` to `String`, but if you're only doing it for the label, then the solution above is better.

Answer (score 4):

The solution offered by Bob Hanlon in his comment certainly works:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, R^"(2)"}]
```

[image: plot1]

but, on MacOS at least, I think Mathematica renders the exponent of $R$ in too large a font. To fix this perceived fault, I suggest the following variation:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, Superscript[R, Style["(2)", 6.5]]}]
```

[image: plot2]