# How to get Mathematica to trigger an event when a Dynamic variable changes?

Tags: dynamic

## How to get Mathematica to trigger an event when a variable inside a `Dynamic[]` changes?

I want Mathematica to `Beep[]` when the colour of a pixel on the screen changes. I recommend wiggling some multicolour window in the middle of the screen to test this program. On Mac you can find the coordinates of pixels at the cursor with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

```
<< GUIKit`;
```

> 

```
num := Evaluate[numb[thePixel]];
thePixel := GUIScreenShot[{{1280, 1281}, {730, 731}}];
numb = Flatten[ImageData[#, "Byte"]] &;


Dynamic[
    Refresh[
        Clear[z];
        z := num // Total;
        Evaluate[z],

        UpdateInterval -> .1
     ]
]
```

Now you should see a number changing as you change the colours of the pixel.

---

## Now how do I get Mathematica to trigger a `Beep[]` when the number changes?

clues welcome :)

I tried both of the solutions in [Detecting changes of variables' values](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41884/detecting-changes-of-variables-values?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this way

```
Dynamic[Refresh[trigger = Total[numb[thePixel]], UpdateInterval -> 0.1, TrackedSymbols :> {}]]
Dynamic[Refresh[trigger; Beep[]; event, TrackedSymbols :> {trigger}]]
```