# Debugging a $RecursionLimit error?

Tags: evaluation, debugging

I sometimes encounter bugs that involve a recursion limit.
It's often very hard to find the origin of the problem.

Would there be a way to copy the stack somewhere and abort the evaluation
in order to know what is causing the error when a message such as the following is emitted (this is just an example)?

```
t = {t}
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of {t}
```

In practice I have a complex program with a user interface and I can't know what's triggering the recursion. Also in Wolfram Workbench, the message breakpoint doesn't stop on such message.

Comment: The topic is related but threads linked by Leonid seem to be quite close: [1514](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1514/5478)

Comment: This helps, thanks Kuba

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the answer of belisarius in [Setting up diagnostic error messages in large Mathematica projects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176612/884752) allows to do exactly what I wanted.

```
$MessagePrePrint = ( #; Print[Stack[_][[;; -5]]]; Abort[]) & 
t = {t} (*prints the stack and aborts*)
```

Specializing $MessagePrint to only print the Stack in a recursion helps even more for this question.

```
$MessagePrePrint=
 If[#===$RecursionLimit::reclim2 || #===$IterationLimit::itlim,
            Print@#;
            Quiet@Print[Stack[_][[;;-5]]];
            Abort[];
            ,
            #
        ]&;
```