# How does exactly Check work?

Tags: programming

Please, consider the following code :

```
k = 0;
ret = Catch[
  Check[
    data = 1/k;
    Print[Pi] ;
    Throw[data, "RETURN"];
    , Throw @ $Failed
    ];
  , "RETURN"
  ]
```

In my mind, it should work this way:

- if `k = 1` (1) `data = 1` (2) `Check` does nothing (because no message has been generated) (3) `Catch` catches `data` (4) `ret = 1`
- if `k = 0` (1) `data = Complex Infinity` (2) `Check` wakes up because a message has been generated `(Power::infy)` and throws `$Failed` (3) but this throw has not the tag `"RETURN"`, therefore it is not caught by `Catch` and a message `(Throw::no catch)` is generated.

On the opposite, what happens is:

- if `k = 1` ... as expected
- ik `k = 0` ... `ret = ComplexInfinity`

To detect the point where I'am reasoning wrong, I added the `Print` command inside: `Pi` is printed even when `k = 0` so I conjecture that `Check` evaluates its first argument, not returning the `failexp` until the whole computation has been completed. Two question:

- is this behaviour related to the `HoldAll` attribute of `Check` ?
- how can I break at the generation of the first message ?

Comment: What about `ret=Check[1/k,Throw@$Failed]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Check` doens't stops the evaluation of its first arguments at the first message generated

```
Check[1/0; Print["inf"], err]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[497]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[497]:= inf
>
> err
> ```

I think you have to put a `Check` around every expression that could generate a message, with some convenience function

```
CheckAndThrow = 
 Function[expr, Quiet@Check[expr, Throw@$Failed], {HoldAll}]

(
 1 + 1;
 1/0 // CheckAndThrow;
 0^0 // CheckAndThrow;
 1 + 1
 )
```

Maybe someone else know a way to intercept a message generation and `Throw` automatically.

---

From the comment of @rcollyer and the links ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1545/16267) and [2](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/YxTwWVL_UCg/IrKs9bhtsdkJ)) provided

> `"Message"` [handler] is invoked for every generated message and passes one argument of the form `Hold[..., ...]` to the handler function, with the second element set to `False` for quieted messages.

So, to get the effect you want, I think you can guard your code, potentially raising messages, in this way

```
Internal`HandlerBlock[
 {"Message", Replace[#, _[_, True] :> Throw@$Failed] &}},

 (* ... code here ... *)

]
```

This will throw `$Failed` for every not `Quiet`-ed message generated inside the guarded block. Because of the general convention about `...Block` of code, at the end of the guarded block, this message handling behavior is discared and any previous message handling routine restored.

Comment: Right. To `Throw`/`Abort` on a message, you use an ``Internal`HandlerBlock``, like in this [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1512/52).

Comment: @rcollyer I suspected that it was an "internal" method...

Comment: Internal`HandlerBlock seems to be an undocumented  feature (at present moment, I'm using ver. 8.0.1.0) and googling doesn't help much. Please, can you provide any reference to study ?

Comment: @mitochondrial Check the [answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1512/52) pointed by rcollyer. I think its the only and best "documentation" available.

Comment: @mitochondrial I also expanded a bit my answer.