# How to replicate x-ticks generated by Plot/LogLinearPlot without a front end?

Tags: plotting, ticks

I want to replicate as closely as possible the *x*-axis `Ticks` specifications generated automatically either by `Plot` or by `LogLinearPlot`.

Furthermore, I need to do this **without a front end** <sup>1</sup>.

I've tried to roll my own, but generating good tick marks programmatically is tricky.

The other approach I've tried (described below) fails when executed without a front end.

---

`$Version`:

```
"10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"
```

---

**Background / tl;dr**

The code below shows how I've produced the desired *x*-tick specs before.  Unfortunately, this code needs a front end to run.

(**NB**: it is safe to assume that the symbol `$plottingFunction` below evaluates either to `Plot` or to `LogLinearPlot`.)

```
getTicks[xrange : {a_, b_}] :=
  (
      dummyPlot = $plottingFunction[
                      Null
                    , {$, a, b}
                    , PlotRange -> {xrange, {0, 1}}
                    , Ticks -> {Automatic, None}
                  ]
    ; absOps = AbsoluteOptions[dummyPlot] (* triggers FrontEndObject::notavail *)
    ; ticks = Ticks /. absOps
    ; (Drop[#, -1] & /@ First[ticks])
  ) /; a < b
```

Basically, `getTicks` "generates" *x*-axis tick specs by ripping them out of a dummy plot.  (The actual code I use is a bit more complicated.  FWIW, I give the full code at the end of this post.)

Unfortunately, function above appears to be reason for why a *Mathematica* script of mine hangs indefinitely when I run it on a headless server.  (The same script runs fine under X11, on my desktop.)

In fact, on the headless server, the call to `AbsoluteOptions` in this function results, indirectly<sup>2</sup>, in the warning

```
FrontEndObject::notavail: A front end is not available; certain operations 
require a front end.
```

I've described this problem in an [earlier post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/133276/2464).

---

Here's the context of the code shown earlier.

```
(* makeGetTicks takes a plotting function (e.g. `Plot`) as argument,
   and returns another function. *)

makeGetTicks = Function[

   $plottingFunction

 , Module[
    {  
       $
     , getTicks
     , dummyPlot
     , absOps
     , ticks
    },

      getTicks[xrange : {a_, b_}] :=
        (
            dummyPlot = $plottingFunction[
                                            Null
                                          , {$, a, b}
                                          , PlotRange -> {xrange, {0, 1}}
                                          , Ticks -> {Automatic, None}
                                         ]
          ; absOps = AbsoluteOptions[dummyPlot]
          ; ticks = Ticks /. absOps
          ; (Drop[#, -1] & /@ First[ticks])
        ) /; a < b

    ; getTicks[xrange : {a_, b_}] := {}

    ; getTicks

   ]];
```

Then, I use `makeGetTicks` to define two other functions:

```
getLinearTicks = makeGetTicks[Plot];
getLogTicks    = makeGetTicks[LogLinearPlot];
```

Note that these functions would be more appropriately named as `makeGetXTicks`, `getLinearXTicks`, `getLogXTicks`.

---

Here's the relevant portion of the call stack (as reported by `Stack[_]`) at the time the `FrontEndObject::notavail` warning is triggered (numbering added):

```
1   absOps$469 = AbsoluteOptions[dummyPlot$469]
2   Module[{System`Dump`plrng$, System`Dump`opts$, System`Dump`names$, System`Dump`vals$, System`Dump`asp$, System`Dump`axes$, System`Dump`x$}, System`Dump`x$ = -Graphics- /. {HoldPattern[Axes -> {System`Dump`a_, System`Dump`a_}] :> Axes -> System`Dump`a, HoldPattern[Frame -> {{System`Dump`a_, System`Dump`a_}, {System`Dump`a_, System`Dump`a_}}] :> Frame -> System`Dump`a}; System`Dump`plrng$ = PlotRange[System`Dump`x$]; System`Dump`names$ = First /@ Options[Head[System`Dump`x$]]; System`Dump`opts$ = Flatten[If[Length[System`Dump`x$] == 0, {}, Drop[List @@ System`Dump`x$, 1]]]; System`Dump`opts$ = Select[System`Dump`opts$, Head[#1] == RuleDelayed || Head[#1] == Rule & ]; System`Dump`opts$ = Join[System`Dump`opts$, Options[Head[System`Dump`x$]]]; System`Dump`opts$ = System`Dump`CheckGopt[System`Dump`x$, System`Dump`opts$, System`Dump`plrng$]; System`Dump`opts$ = Prepend[System`Dump`opts$, PlotRange -> System`Dump`plrng$]; System`Dump`axes$ = FullAxes[System`Dump`x$]; If[ListQ[System`Dump`axes$], System`Dump`opts$ = Join[System`Dump`axes$, System`Dump`opts$]]; System`Dump`opts$ = Join[System`Dump`GetMesh[System`Dump`x$, System`Dump`opts$], System`Dump`opts$]; System`Dump`vals$ = System`Dump`names$ /. System`Dump`opts$; System`Dump`opts$ = Transpose[{System`Dump`names$, System`Dump`vals$}]; System`Dump`opts$ = Apply[{#1, If[MemberQ[{AxesLabel, FrameLabel, PlotLabel}, #1], #2, N[#2]]} & , System`Dump`opts$, {1}]; (Rule @@ #1 & ) /@ System`Dump`opts$]
3   System`Dump`x$38165 = -Graphics- /. {HoldPattern[Axes -> {System`Dump`a_, System`Dump`a_}] :> Axes -> System`Dump`a, HoldPattern[Frame -> {{System`Dump`a_, System`Dump`a_}, {System`Dump`a_, System`Dump`a_}}] :> Frame -> System`Dump`a}; System`Dump`plrng$38165 = PlotRange[System`Dump`x$38165]; System`Dump`names$38165 = First /@ Options[Head[System`Dump`x$38165]]; System`Dump`opts$38165 = Flatten[If[Length[System`Dump`x$38165] == 0, {}, Drop[List @@ System`Dump`x$38165, 1]]]; System`Dump`opts$38165 = Select[System`Dump`opts$38165, Head[#1] == RuleDelayed || Head[#1] == Rule & ]; System`Dump`opts$38165 = Join[System`Dump`opts$38165, Options[Head[System`Dump`x$38165]]]; System`Dump`opts$38165 = System`Dump`CheckGopt[System`Dump`x$38165, System`Dump`opts$38165, System`Dump`plrng$38165]; System`Dump`opts$38165 = Prepend[System`Dump`opts$38165, PlotRange -> System`Dump`plrng$38165]; System`Dump`axes$38165 = FullAxes[System`Dump`x$38165]; If[ListQ[System`Dump`axes$38165], System`Dump`opts$38165 = Join[System`Dump`axes$38165, System`Dump`opts$38165]]; System`Dump`opts$38165 = Join[System`Dump`GetMesh[System`Dump`x$38165, System`Dump`opts$38165], System`Dump`opts$38165]; System`Dump`vals$38165 = System`Dump`names$38165 /. System`Dump`opts$38165; System`Dump`opts$38165 = Transpose[{System`Dump`names$38165, System`Dump`vals$38165}]; System`Dump`opts$38165 = Apply[{#1, If[MemberQ[{AxesLabel, FrameLabel, PlotLabel}, #1], #2, N[#2]]} & , System`Dump`opts$38165, {1}]; (Rule @@ #1 & ) /@ Sy
4   System`Dump`axes$38165 = FullAxes[System`Dump`x$38165]
5   FullAxes[-Graphics-]
6   ConvertToPostScript[Cell[BoxData[FormBox[RowBox[{-, 500}], TraditionalForm]], {}, ShowCellBracket -> False, PageWidth :> Infinity]]
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> The code is supposed to run on a headless server.  I'm aware of the technique of using Xvfb to run *Mathematica* on a headless server, but unfortunately, but I don't have the user permissions required to run Xvfb on the headless server I need to run this script on.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> According to the value returned by `Stack[_]`, the *immediate* trigger for the warning is a call to `ConvertToPostScript`.</sup>

Comment: Is using `Xvnc` an option? I don't think it requires any special user privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from version 10 plot-generating functions [use](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57427/280) `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` and `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` for generating ticks specifications. These functions are defined in the Kernel, so you don't need FrontEnd. In [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/107473/280) answer I provide usage examples for all types of linear and log-plots.

For example the following generates `FrameTicks` specification identical to what `LogLinearPlot` generates (`Most` is added to fix the bug described in the [linked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/57427/280) answer):

```
Clear[logLinearFrameTicks]
logLinearFrameTicks[{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}] := 
{{Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][ymin, ymax], 
  Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][ymin, ymax]}, 
 {Most /@ Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][xmin, xmax], 
  Most /@ Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}][xmin, xmax]}};

logLinearFrameTicks[{1, 10}, {-10, 1}] // Short
```

> ```
> {{{{2.,2,{0.01,0.}},{4.,4,{0.01,0.}},{6.,6,{0.01,0.}},<<16>>,{9.,,{0.005,0.}},{9.5,,{0.005,0.}}},{<<1>>}},{<<1>>}}
> ```

Comment: I think you get notified of edits, but just in case: I edited your code to swap xmin ↔ymin, xmax ↔ymax.  (As I understand it, the ordering of frame ticks is {{*left*, *right*}, {*bottom*, *top*}}.)

Answer (score 3):

`AbsoluteOptions` seems to be poorly maintained. One alternative would be to use `CustomTicks` and this code to extract the ticks:

```
<< "CustomTicks`"
dummyPlot = 
  Block[{x, xmin = 0, xmax = 4}, 
   Plot[Null, {x, xmin, xmax}, PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {0, 1}}, 
    Ticks -> {LinTicks, None}]];
ticks=Ticks /. List @@ dummyPlot[[2]];
```

Just replace `xmin` and `xmax` with your required range.

Edit: Of course, you can also just use the result of `LinTicks[xmin,xmax]`, which is identical to the result provided above. You can then apply your further code to strip the line style column of the ticks table:

```
Drop[#, -1] & /@ LinTicks[xmin, xmax]
```

I believe that is what your function `getTicks` should return.