# customisable error checking, message handling code

Tags: message-coding, error-tracking, usage-messages

I have an iterated computation running in a while loop, which is bound to fail at some point, at which point I want it to stop, e.g.

```
currentSolution = 0;
Block[{i = -3},
 While[i < 3,
  correction = 1/i;
  currentSolution += correction;
  i++;
  ];
 currentSolution
 ]
```

Of course in my actual application the computation is more complicated, I don't know ahead of time when it will fail, and the `While` condition depends on `result` too.

I want the `While` loop to stop at any error message, suppress Mathematica's messages and show my own.

Furthermore I want to be able to easily customise this, i.e. turn off the error checking completely or change the messages that are shown or that trigger the error.

For this I've written the general code:

```
Attributes[checkError] = {HoldFirst};
checkError[{expr_, failCode_}, myErrorMessage_, myErrorMessageParams_,
   messagesIgnored_, messagesNotShown_, messagesShown_] := 
 If[$CheckError === False, expr, 
  Quiet[Check[Quiet[expr, messagesIgnored], failCode;
    Message[myErrorMessage, myErrorMessageParams];
    Return[$Failed, Block]], messagesNotShown, messagesShown]]
```

and a more specific one that uses the above:

```
Attributes[checkError2] = {HoldFirst};
checkError2[expr_, params_] := 
 checkError[{expr, currentSolution = $Failed}, my::message, 
  params, $MessagesIgnored, $MessagesNotShown, $MessagesShown]

$CheckError = True;
$MessagesIgnored = {};
$MessagesNotShown = All;
$MessagesShown = {my::message, General::stop};
my::message = "Failed at `1`!";
```

which I would want to use as:

```
currentSolution = 0;
Block[{i = -3},
 While[i < 3,
  correction = checkError2[1/i, i];
  currentSolution += correction;
  i++;
  ];
 currentSolution
 ]
```

The intention is for this to show `my::message` and output `$Failed`.

There are some problems with this code though:

at the above it doesn't recognise the messages in `messagesShown` nor `myErrorMessage`:

[image]

When I explicitly copy `{my::message, General::stop}` into `messagesShown` in `checkError` these errors disappear and it outputs `$Failed`. When I do the same with `my::message` that also displays.
But for instance replacing `messagesShown` with `Evaluate@messagesShown` does not work.

Another issue is that even if it worked, `messagesIgnored` would indeed be ignored by `Check` because the `Quiet` is inside, but they would also obviously not be shown, which is not what I want, that should be controlled by `messagesNotShown` and `messagesShown`.
Unlike for `Quiet` there is no additional argument for `Check` that controls which messages **not** to check for.

How do I fix these issues and make this code work as intended?

Comment: @Alan No particular reason (but I just checked that with `Module` it gives the same error).

Comment: @Alan 
What do you mean? I am `Check`ing the errors that this code is supposed to encounter, while the errors that this code itself generates are actual errors that preventie it from functioning.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html

Comment: @Alan Yes I know about `Check`, it's there in between two `Quiet`s in my code `checkError`. Messages blocked by the inner `Quiet` are ignored by `Check` (but are also not printed obviously, which is not what I want), while the outer `Quiet` of course doesn't affect `Check`. If you are trying to say that `Check` already has all the functionality that I want then I don't see it.

Comment: Do named message groups not meet your needs?  Sorry if not.

Comment: @Alan, No, I want to for instance be able to `Check` for all messages except one or several. `Quiet` supports this with `Quiet[...,All,notQuiet]` but `Check` does not. But I also don't understand why the messages are not recognised in my code.

Comment: Regarding the errors you get: The problem is that `my::message` evaluates to the string ``"Failed at `1`"`` before the `HoldAll` attribute from `Quiet` has a chance to prevent this. To work around this, you have to pass in the messages in some held form and then carefully insert them into `Quiet`, e.g. using, `myQuiet[expr_,Hold[messages__]]:=Quiet[expr,{messages}]`, `Attributes[myQuiet]={HoldFirst}` where `messages` will be `Hold[my::Message,…]`

Comment: For the other part, you could use [``Internal`HandlerBlock``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1545) to build your own `Check`-like function