# Ignore message in `Check` without silencing

Tags: programming, error-tracking, usage-messages

`Check[expr,failexpr,checkedMessages]` will evaluate `expr` and if it encounters any of the messages in `checkedMessages` it will evaluate `failexpr` and return that instead.

But how can I `Check` for **all** messages except let's say one?

`Quiet` has the syntax `Quiet[expr,All,notQuiet]` that will suppress all messages except those in `notQuiet`, but `Check` does not have this option.

A workaround is to use `Quiet` inside `Check`:

```
Check[Quiet[expr,ignoredMessages],failexpr,checkedMessages]
```

which will trigger for any message that is contained in `checkedMessages` but not in `ignoredMessages`.
However this has the unintended side effect of also (obviously) `Quiet`ing the `ignoredMessages`.

So for instance the desired function

```
myCheck[expr_,failexpr_,checkedMessages_,ignoredMessages_]:=..?
```

should do this:

```
myCheck[1/0,1,All,{}]
(* show message Power::infy *)
(* return 1 *)
```

but

```
myCheck[1/0,1,All,{Power::infy}]
(* show message Power::infy *)
(* return ComplexInfinity *)
```

(This is a more succinct question about one of the issues in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/185346/customisable-error-checking-message-handling-code))

Comment: I'm pretty sure `Check[]` does not abort an evaluation but let's it run its course; then it `failexpr` is evaluated.  `Catch@Check[Check[res = expr, Throw@res, ignoredMessages], failexpr,  messages]` might work for you. (It's probably better to use `Throw` and `Catch` with tags.)

Comment: @Kuba Sorry you and Michael are right of course that `Check` doesn't abort the evaluation, that was sloppy. I don't need it to though, I've added two examples.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry I shouldn't have written that `Check` aborts the evaluation, it doesn't and I don't need it to. I want the functionality of `Check` but just with the addition that it can check for all messages except some specified list. Writing your suggestion as `myCheck[expr_, failexpr_, checkedMessages_,ignoredMessages_]:= Block[{res}, Catch@Check[Check[res =expr, Throw@res, ignoredMessages], failexpr,checkedMessages]]` gives an error in my examples regarding `All`. This can be solved by replacing `checkedMessages` by `Evaluate[checkedMessages/.All->Sequence[]]`...

Comment: @MichaelE2 ..and similar for `ignoredMessages`, but then it returns `ComplexInfinity` in both examples above.

Comment: The problem with my proposal is that when multiple messages are emitted, some to be ignored and some not, they are all ignored.  I suppose the desired behavior if any `checkedMessages` are emitted is to return `failexpr`, yes?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, return `failexpr` without suppressing any of the messages, even the ignored ones.

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1

```
ClearAll[myCheck];
SetAttributes[myCheck, HoldAll];
myCheck[expr_, failexpr_, checkedMessages_List, 
   ignoredMessages_List] := Module[{res, c, i},
   c = Alternatives @@ HoldForm /@ Unevaluated@checkedMessages /. 
     All -> _;
   i = Alternatives @@ HoldForm /@ Unevaluated@ignoredMessages /. 
     All -> _;
   Check[res = expr, 
    If[AnyTrue[$MessageList, MatchQ[#, Except[i, c]] &], failexpr, 
     res]]
   ];
myCheck[expr_, failexpr_, checkedMessages_, ignoredMessages_List] := 
  myCheck[expr, failexpr, {checkedMessages}, ignoredMessages];
myCheck[expr_, failexpr_, checkedMessages_, ignoredMessages_] := 
  myCheck[expr, failexpr, checkedMessages, {ignoredMessages}];

myCheck[0/0, "Oops!", All, Power::infy]
```

Examples:

> ```
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.
>
> (* Out[]= "Oops!" *)
> ```

```
myCheck[0/0, "Oops!", All, {Power::infy, Infinity::indet}]
```

> ```
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.
>
> (* Out[]= Indeterminate *)
> ```

#### Method 2

I might prefer a pattern-oriented check.

```
ClearAll[myCheck2];
SetAttributes[myCheck2, HoldAll];
myCheck2[expr_, failexpr_, msgPat_] := Module[{res, failPat},
   failPat = 
    Hold[msgPat] /. {hm : HoldForm[_MessageName] :> hm, 
       m_MessageName :> HoldForm[m]} // ReleaseHold;
   Check[res = expr, 
    If[AnyTrue[$MessageList, MatchQ[#, failPat] &], failexpr, res]]
   ];
```

Examples:

```
myCheck2[0/0, "Oops!", Except[Power::infy]]
```

> ```
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.
>
> (* Out[]= "Oops!" *)
> ```

```
myCheck2[0/0, "Oops!", Except[Power::infy | Infinity::indet]]
```

> ```
> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.
>
> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered.
>
> (* Out[] = Indeterminate *)
> ```

```
myCheck2[Sin[x, y], "Oops!", Except[_::"argx"]]
```

> ```
> Sin::argx: Sin called with 2 arguments; 1 argument is expected.
>
> (* Out[]= Sin[x, y] *)
> ```