# Is it possible to trigger some Mathematica code when an error of the type StringTake::take happens?

Tags: debugging, message-coding

I process data from various sources (databases) that are formatted very inconsistently. I would like to be able to process them finally summarized in one piece.

My code consists of many cases of StringTake and RegularExpression. Therefore a message `StringTake::take` does not really localize the place where the bug sits.

My function processes the imported data line by line with my function called `DataMining[fileName]`. It is applied as `DataMining /@ FileNames["*"]`.

There are variables in my function `Datamining`, which contain the last read record, count, how many records from the just read file are already processed as output records and there is also a variable with the last read record itself.

But with very few of the many files it happens that error messages of the kind `StringTake::take` etc occur. I would like to set a global variable "debug" to a certain number>0 and the I want to restart the current turn of the processing loop with the same record that caused the error message. The debug then enables all preprogrammed test outputs for that record.

Then I could quickly locate the cause of my bug, because my code is already armed with lines `If[debug>..., Print["No x:",....]]` which issue the messages to locate the print statement and the states of the relevant varibales at those places "No x:", ... .

But because of the many files and many lines in them (most of them more than 100000 lines), switching this debug mechanism on from the beginning would produce too much output.

Even switching it on for a single file would cause very much output.

**How to make the first error message of the type `StringTake::take` call an interrupt routine and interrupt the normal flow of the program, set the variable debug to a given level and let the processing loop restart with the last read record which is still in memory** in order to see exactly the history leading to the error message `StringTake::take`?

Comment: [``Internal`AddHandler``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/how-to-abort-on-any-message-generated) would probably do it.

Comment: Have a look also at [`CheckReturn`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CheckReturn/), which is a higher level function implemented using ``Internal`AddHandler``.

Comment: There is also the debugger (Evaluation > Debugger) which can be used to set a breakpoint on specific messages, which then allows you to investigate the stack among other things