# How to express Error Message as 'Output Cell'?

Tags: message-coding

I got a random error message.

```
expr = N[Pi, a]
expr = Sin[x,
```

[image]
[image]

The error message does not appear in the 'Output Cell'.

```
In : msg = "How do I write the code?" 
            However, you must write the code using only 'expr' or 'N[Pi,a]'
Out : "N::precbd :: Requested precision a is not a machine-sized real number
                    between $MinPrecision and $MaxPrecision."
```

I want to assign an error message to the symbol and continue the additional work. What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

The typical way to "capture" errors is with `Check`:

```
expr = Check[N[Pi, a], "the result if fail"]
```

If `N[Pi, a]` generates any messages, then `expr` will be set to `"the result if fail"`. So, you can create whatever failure result you want and do subsequent processing with it.

Comment: Can't you express it with the error message above instead of "the result if fail"?

Comment: There are ways to access the messages (see @kglr's answer), but generally that's an ineffective way to deal with them. You can tell `Check` which specific messages you care about, if that would be helpful to you. Also, just in case it wasn't clear, you can put whatever you want in place of `"the result if fail"`.

Comment: for instance, `Check[N[Pi, a], $MessageList]`

Answer (score 3):

#### [\$Pre](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Pre.html) + [EvaluationData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationData.html)

```
SetAttributes[saveMessages, HoldAll];
msgs = {};
saveMessages[input_] := (msgs = 
    Join[msgs, EvaluationData[input]@"MessagesText"]; input);

$Pre = saveMessages;
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### DownValues @ [MessageList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MessageList.html)

[image]

```
Join @@ Values @ DownValues  @ MessageList
```

[image]

Comment: The confirmation was late. Thank you for your reply. As a result of the test, two confirmations were needed. (1) Messages generated when executing "Sin[x," are not contained in msg. (2) Using 'Check', is it possible to get msgs as the output value every time an error occurs?

Answer (score 2):

Adapting the techique here: [How to abort on any message generated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/how-to-abort-on-any-message-generated/1545#1545)

```
messageHandler = Return[{##}, Internal`HandlerBlock] &;
expr = Internal`HandlerBlock[
  {"Message", messageHandler},
  1./0.
  ]
```

> [image]

I'm unsure just what you would want `expr` to be. The message you see in the front end is the typeset output of `Message`. It's probably possible to capture the box form of it, but it doesn't seem that useful to me.

```
expr // InputForm
```

> ```
> (*  {Hold[Message[Power::infy, HoldForm[0.^(-1)]], True]}  *)
> ```